# Can't install python mysql library on Mac Mavericks

Tags: python, django, macos, osx-mavericks, mysql-python

It was working like a charm before the update from Mountain Lion.

After the update it is broken and I cannot get the environment up again.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

The error is bolded, below.

```
fedorius@this:~$ pip install mysql-python
Downloading/unpacking mysql-python
  Downloading MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108kB): 108kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/21/zjvwzn891jnf4rnp526y13200000gn/T/pip_build_fedorius/mysql-python/setup.py) egg_info for package mysql-python

Installing collected packages: mysql-python
  Running setup.py install for mysql-python
    building '_mysql' extension
    cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -pipe -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 -I/usr/local/mysql/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/_mysql.o -Os -g -fno-strict-aliasing -arch x86_64
    clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
    clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
    error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/21/zjvwzn891jnf4rnp526y13200000gn/T/pip_build_fedorius/mysql-python/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/21/zjvwzn891jnf4rnp526y13200000gn/T/pip-_yi6sy-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/MySQLdb

copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/MySQLdb

creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

running build_ext

building '_mysql' extension

creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -pipe -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 -I/usr/local/mysql/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/_mysql.o -Os -g -fno-strict-aliasing -arch x86_64

**clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1**

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/21/zjvwzn891jnf4rnp526y13200000gn/T/pip_build_fedorius/mysql-python/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/21/zjvwzn891jnf4rnp526y13200000gn/T/pip-_yi6sy-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/21/zjvwzn891jnf4rnp526y13200000gn/T/pip_build_fedorius/mysql-python
Storing debug log for failure in /var/folders/21/zjvwzn891jnf4rnp526y13200000gn/T/tmp5QBn55
```

UPDATE:

As suggested, I've added

export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments

But it changed the error to

```
error: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so: Permission denied
```

I just chmoded this directory to allow writing and it worked :)
This is due to mixing macports, easy_install and pip... shame on me.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The problem is due to changes introduced in Xcode 5.1 and due to the way the Apple-supplied system Python 2.7 is built.  Try adding these environment variable values before running `pip`:

```
export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
```

See [clang error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' (python package installation failure)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/clang-error-unknown-argument-mno-fused-madd-psycopg2-installation-failure/22322645#22322645) for more information.

UPDATE [2014-05-16]: As expected, Apple has fixed this problem with updated system Pythons (2.7, 2.6, and 2.5) in `OS X 10.9.3` so the workaround is no longer necessary when using the latest Mavericks and `Xcode 5.1+`.  However, as of now, the workaround is still required for `OS X 10.8.x` (Mountain Lion, currently 10.8.5) if you are using `Xcode 5.1+` there.

Comment: Thanks! Now I've got a permission error... And if I run with sudo, I still have the same problem.

Comment: You probably need to redo the exports under `sudo`.  Try something like: `sudo bash`, `export ...`, `export ...`, `pip ... `.

Comment: you're a lifesaver Ned!  this worked for installing Pillow as well

Comment: You just saved my whole weekend. I wasn't able to fix the bug on my own. :) Worked without any problem.

Comment: It's a silly bug due to lack of testing on Apple's part: introducing new features in Xcode in the middle of an OS X release cycle.  I expect it will be fixed in the next maintenance release of OS X.

Comment: You may need to run sudo -E pip install MySQL-python to load the environment variables as shown in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/clang-error-unknown-argument-mno-fused-madd-python-package-installation-fa#comment34219420_22322645

Answer (score 0):

Building on Ned's answer:

Since I don't want to use sudo to install packages (I am using virtual environments) or affect my golbal environment, I added the two variables to the *single execution* of `pip install`:

`CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments pip install -r requirements.txt`