# How to decode a QR-code image in (preferably pure) Python?

Tags: python, decode, qr-code, zxing, zbar

> **TL;DR**: I need a way to decode a QR-code from an image file using (preferable pure) Python.

I've got a jpg file with a QR-code which I want to decode using Python. I've found a couple libraries which claim to do this:

**PyQRCode** ([website here](http://pyqrcode.sourceforge.net/)) which supposedly can decode qr codes from images by simply providing a path like this:

```
import sys, qrcode
d = qrcode.Decoder()
if d.decode('out.png'):
    print 'result: ' + d.result
else:
    print 'error: ' + d.error
```

So I simply installed it using `sudo pip install pyqrcode`. The thing I find strange about the example code above however, is that it only imports `qrcode` (and not `pyqrcode` though) Since I think `qrcode` refers to [this library](https://github.com/lincolnloop/python-qrcode) which can only *generate* qr-code images it kind of confused me. So I tried the code above with both `pyqrcode` and `qrcode`, but both fail at the second line saying `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Decoder'`. Furthermore, [the website](http://pyqrcode.sourceforge.net/) refers to Ubuntu 8.10 (which came out more than 6 years ago) and I can't find a public (git or other) repository of it to check the latest commit. So I moved on to the next library:

**ZBar** ([website here](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/)) claims to be `"an open source software suite for reading bar codes from various sources, such as image files."` So I tried installing it on Mac OSX running `sudo pip install zbar`. This fails with `error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1`. I tried to suggestions in the answers to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697440/cc-failed-with-exit-status-1-error-when-install-python-library), but I can't seem to solve it. So I decided to move on again:

**QRTools**, which according to [this blogpost](http://zleap.net/python-qr-code-reader/) can decode images easily by using the following code:

```
from qrtools import QR
myCode = QR(filename=u"/home/psutton/Documents/Python/qrcodes/qrcode.png")
if myCode.decode():
  print myCode.data
  print myCode.data_type
  print myCode.data_to_string()
```

So I tried installing it using `sudo pip install qrtools`, which can't find anything. I also tried it with `python-qrtools`, `qr-tools`, `python-qrtools` and a couple more combinations, but unfortunately to no avail. I suppose it refers to [this repo](https://launchpad.net/qr-tools) which says it is based on ZBar (see above). Although I want to run my code on Heroku (and thus prefer a pure Python solution) I successfully installed it on a Linux box (with `sudo apt-get install python-qrtools`) and tried running it:

```
from qrtools import QR
c = QR(filename='/home/kramer65/qrcode.jpg')
c.data  # prints u'NULL'
c.data_type  # prints u'text'
c.data_to_string()  # prints '\xef\xbb\xbfNULL' where I expect an int (being `1234567890`)
```

Although this seems to decode it, It doesn't seem to do it correctly. It furthermore needs ZBar and is thus not pure Python. So I decided to find yet another library.

**PyXing** ([website here](https://github.com/holizz/pyxing)) is supposedly a Python port of the popular Java [ZXing library](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/), but the initial and only commit is 6 years old and the project has no readme or documentation whatsoever.

For the rest I found a couple qr-**en**coders (not **de**coders) and some API endpoints which can decode for you. Since I don't like this service to be dependent on other API endpoints I would want to keep the decoding local though.

So to conclude; would anybody know how I can decode QR-codes from images in (preferable pure) Python? All tips are welcome!

Comment: It should be:  'if myCode.decode("/home/kramer65/qrcode.jpg")'  and not 
'QR(filename='/home/kramer65/qrcode.jpg')'

Comment: I feel it is worth mentioning a follow-up question posed by **@kramer65** about installing `zbar` with `pip`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406641/how-to-install-python-bindings-originating-from-an-apt-package

Answer (score 120, accepted):

You can try the following steps and code using `qrtools`:

- Create a `qrcode` file, if not already existing

  - I used [`pyqrcode`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyQRCode) for doing this, which can be installed using `pip install pyqrcode`
  - And then use the code:

    ```
    >>> import pyqrcode
    >>> qr = pyqrcode.create("HORN O.K. PLEASE.")
    >>> qr.png("horn.png", scale=6)
    ```
- Decode an existing `qrcode` file using [`qrtools`](https://launchpad.net/qr-tools)

  - Install `qrtools` using `sudo apt-get install python-qrtools`
  - Now use the following code within your python prompt

    ```
    >>> import qrtools
    >>> qr = qrtools.QR()
    >>> qr.decode("horn.png")
    >>> print qr.data
    u'HORN O.K. PLEASE.'
    ```

Here is the complete code in a single run:

```
In [2]: import pyqrcode
In [3]: qr = pyqrcode.create("HORN O.K. PLEASE.")
In [4]: qr.png("horn.png", scale=6)
In [5]: import qrtools
In [6]: qr = qrtools.QR()
In [7]: qr.decode("horn.png")
Out[7]: True
In [8]: print qr.data
HORN O.K. PLEASE.
```

***Caveats***

- You might need to install `PyPNG` using `pip install pypng` for using `pyqrcode`
- In case you have `PIL` installed, you might get `IOError: decoder zip not available`. In that case, [try uninstalling and reinstalling `PIL`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12359864/1860929) using:

  ```
  pip uninstall PIL
  pip install PIL
  ```
- If that doesn't work, try using `Pillow` instead

  ```
  pip uninstall PIL
  pip install pillow
  ```

Comment: Hi mu 無, thanks for your answer. Although qrtools requires zbar and is thus not pure python, it does indeed work now. The main problem is now that I need to install the zbar python binding on heroku, about which I asked a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406641/how-to-install-python-bindings-originating-from-an-apt-package . I'm going to accept your answer, but I would greatly appreciate if you also have a look at my other question so that I can solve running qrtools on heroku. Thanks a million!

Comment: @kramer65 Unfortunately, I don't have much experience with heroku, so am not sure how packages are installed there...

Comment: This does not work, gives Exception: tostring() has been removed.

Comment: @Bhishan might be a case where newer packages give the error, ask a new question and share a link here ...

Comment: @BhishanPoudel I encountered this as well. It seems the bug has been fixed and should appear in the next release. For anyone encountering this, you can edit line 181 of /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qrtools.py (location may vary) and replace "tostring" with "tobytes". It's running nicely for me now.

Comment: not works. AttributeError: module 'qrtools' has no attribute 'QR'

Comment: @SaeedMohtasham try `from qrtools import qrtools`

Comment: @mu-無 Hi, on `qr.decode('myPicture.png')`, I get an `AttributeError: module 'zbar' has no attribute 'ImageScanner'` error, any idea ?

Comment: No module named zbar when importing qrtools

Comment: Note from 2021 - qrtools does not support python3, since its dependency zbar does not support python3. Use the solution with pyzbar+PIL instead.

Comment: Strictly speaking this flow uses a bunch of more or less outdated libraries. What would be nice is to have a reverse version of libZint, which can decode barcodes depending on the pattern. Given the specification (ISO), it should be possible to do in pure Python using a single image reader library only.

Answer (score 38):

The following code works fine with me:

```
brew install zbar
pip install pyqrcode
pip install pyzbar
```

For QR code image creation:

```
import pyqrcode
qr = pyqrcode.create("test1")
qr.png("test1.png", scale=6)
```

For QR code decoding:

```
from PIL import Image
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
data = decode(Image.open('test1.png'))
print(data)
```

that prints the result:

```
[Decoded(data=b'test1', type='QRCODE', rect=Rect(left=24, top=24, width=126, height=126), polygon=[Point(x=24, y=24), Point(x=24, y=150), Point(x=150, y=150), Point(x=150, y=24)])]
```

Comment: for the above solution to work, u also need to run pip install pypng && pip install image

Answer (score 15):

I found a new and effective way, just using cv2. The code below will decode a QR code.

```
import cv2
# Name of the QR Code Image file
filename = "attandence_Record_QR_code.png"
# read the QRCODE image
image = cv2.imread(filename)
# initialize the cv2 QRCode detector
detector = cv2.QRCodeDetector()
# detect and decode
data, vertices_array, binary_qrcode = detector.detectAndDecode(image)
# if there is a QR code
# print the data
if vertices_array is not None:
  print("QRCode data:")
  print(data)
else:
  print("There was some error")
```

Comment: can;t decode image like tinyurl.com/cv2qrerr

Comment: I can't see the error your link is down. This code works most of the times. And an future update of cv2 can help you.

Comment: @CSQGB i found your problem, in your image it don't have any white edge background that's why it cannot be detected,after i do some GIMP (Linux Photoshop ) i got the result,

Comment: This is a superb answer, it works flawlessly on Windows.

Answer (score 8):

I'm answering only the part of the question about `zbar` installation.

I spent <strike>nearly half an hour</strike> a few hours to make it work on Windows + Python 2.7 64-bit, so here are additional notes to the accepted answer:

- Download https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/ZBarWin64/releases/download/v0.10/zbar-0.10-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
- Install it with `pip install zbar-0.10-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl`
- If Python reports an `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.` when doing `import zbar`, then you will *just* need to install the [Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for VS 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=40784) (I spent a lot of time here, trying to recompile unsuccessfully...)
- Required too: libzbar64-0.dll must be in a folder which is in the PATH. In my case I copied it to "C:\Python27\libzbar64-0.dll" (which is in the PATH). If it still does not work, add this:

  ```
  import os
  os.environ['PATH'] += ';C:\\Python27' 
  import zbar
  ```

PS: Making it work with Python 3.x is even more difficult: [Compile zbar for Python 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59969573/compile-zbar-for-python-3-x-windows-x64).

PS2: I just tested [pyzbar](https://pypi.org/project/pyzbar/) with `pip install pyzbar` and it's MUCH easier, it works out-of-the-box (the only thing is you need to have VC Redist 2013 files installed). It is also recommended to use this library in [this pyimagesearch.com article](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/05/21/an-opencv-barcode-and-qr-code-scanner-with-zbar/).

Answer (score 6):

There is a library called [BoofCV which claims to better than ZBar and other libraries](https://boofcv.org/index.php?title=Performance:QrCode).
Here are the steps to use that (any OS).

Pre-requisites:

- Ensure JDK 14+ is installed and set in $PATH
- `pip install pyboof`

Class to decode:

```py
import os
import numpy as np
import pyboof as pb

pb.init_memmap() #Optional

class QR_Extractor:
    # Src: github.com/lessthanoptimal/PyBoof/blob/master/examples/qrcode_detect.py
    def __init__(self):
        self.detector = pb.FactoryFiducial(np.uint8).qrcode()
    
    def extract(self, img_path):
        if not os.path.isfile(img_path):
            print('File not found:', img_path)
            return None
        image = pb.load_single_band(img_path, np.uint8)
        self.detector.detect(image)
        qr_codes = []
        for qr in self.detector.detections:
            qr_codes.append({
                'text': qr.message,
                'points': qr.bounds.convert_tuple()
            })
        return qr_codes
```

Usage:

```py
qr_scanner = QR_Extractor()
output = qr_scanner.extract('Your-Image.jpg')
print(output)
```

Tested and works on Python 3.8 (Windows & Ubuntu)

Comment: This is the correct answer for original question : A Pure Python library for QR-Code scanning. All other answers required external library setups.
Tested on macOS in a virtualenv with Python3.8.4.

Comment: It seems to be trying to call java:  
jar_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(jar_path),"PyBoof-all.jar")
So not really pure Python ...

Comment: No pure python-based QR decoder would be fast enough for real-time. Even OpenCV-Python runs on a C++-core

Comment: I get "
  File "C:\pythonProject\qrcode\venv\lib\site-packages\pyboof\common.py", line 179, in mmap_array_java_to_python mm.seek(0) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'seek'.

Comment: Please [raise an issue in the PyBoof repo](https://github.com/lessthanoptimal/PyBoof/issues).

Answer (score 5):

In 2022 using Python 3 this is what worked for me.

### Step 1: Install the zbar library

macOS:

```bash
brew install zbar
```

If you get an `'Unable to find zbar shared library'` ImportError then do:

```bash
mkdir ~/lib
ln -s $(brew --prefix zbar)/lib/libzbar.dylib ~/lib/libzbar.dylib
```

Ubuntu/Debian Linux:

```bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install zbar-tools
```

Windows:

According to the [pyzbar project page](https://pypi.org/project/pyzbar/): Install "Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013. Install vcredist_x64.exe if using 64-bit Python, vcredist_x86.exe if using 32-bit Python."

### Step 2: Install the PIP Python packages

```bash
pip3 install opencv-python
pip3 install pyzbar
```

### Step 3: Create a Python script

Create a `.py` script and run the following:

```py
import cv2 as cv
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode

qrcode_img = 'path/to/qrcode/img.png'
img = cv.imread(qrcode_img)
decoded_data = decode(img)

# parse the decoded zbar data
url = decoded_data[0].data.decode()
print(f'URL: {url}')
```

Answer (score 2):

### For Windows using `ZBar`

Pre-requisites:

- Install ZBar by either:

  - Install Chocolatey and `choco install zbar`
  - Or use [Windows Installer for ZBar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/download.html)
- `pip install pyzbar`

To decode:

```py
from PIL import Image
from pyzbar import pyzbar

img = Image.open('My-Image.jpg')
output = pyzbar.decode(img)
print(output)
```

---

Alternatively, you can also try using `ZBarLight` by setting it up as mentioned here:
https://pypi.org/project/zbarlight/

Comment: I use exactly this on ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I followed your steps on windows 10 but didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

[PyBoof](https://pypi.org/project/PyBoof/) is a wrapper around [BoofCV](https://boofcv.org) and has an easy to use QR Code reader. It also give you access to a ton of information about the QR, e.g. number of bit errors, precise location, raw message, ...

```
image = pb.load_single_band(data_path, np.uint8)

detector = pb.FactoryFiducial(np.uint8).qrcode()
detector.detect(image)

for qr in detector.detections:
    print("Message: " + qr.message)
    print("     at: " + str(qr.bounds))
```

Comment: `Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: pyboof/PyBoofEntryPoint has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0` -- yeah let me mess up 544765 other tools by fixing java version for this one

Answer (score 1):

first intsall
pip install pyzbar

then:

```
import cv2 as cv
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
     img=cv.imread('/path/img.jpg')
     objs=decode(img)
     for obj in objs:
         print('data: ', obj)
```