# How to install Python bindings originating from an apt package?

Tags: python, linux, debian, apt, zbar

I've got a website hosted at [Heroku](http://heroku.com/), and I now want to use the `python-qrtools` package which uses the [ZBar bar code scanner](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/). On a regular debian (based) I can do a simple:

```
sudo apt-get install python-qrtools
```

According to the command `dpkg-query -L python-qrtools`, this installs the following:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qrtools-1.2.egg-info
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qrtools.py
/usr/share/doc/python-qrtools/copyright
/usr/share/doc/python-qrtools/changelog.Debian.gz
```

When I look at the imports of `qrtools.py`, it also does an `import zbar`, which is (as far as I understand) the python binding for the Zbar package ([Pypi link here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zbar)). I'm kinda surprised that zbar or its python bindings are not in the list with the `python-qrtools` apt package though. So my first question:

**When and where is this zbar package installed?**

Moving on I decided to install ZBar and the python binding for it on Heroku. I managed to install ZBar using [this ZBar buildpack](https://github.com/ballantyne/heroku-buildpack-zbar) so I only need to instal the zbar Python binding. From the python command line I already see that it is a binding originating from a .so file:

```
>>> import zbar
>>> zbar.__file__
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zbar.so'
```

So I did a simple `sudo pip install zbar`, which unfortunately results in a massive compiling error which I pasted below. So my main question is actually the following:

**How do I install the zbar python bindings separately (so without apt)? All tips are welcome!**

```
Downloading/unpacking zbar
  Downloading zbar-0.10.tar.bz2
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/zbar/setup.py) egg_info for package zbar

Installing collected packages: zbar
  Running setup.py install for zbar
    building 'zbar' extension
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c zbarmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/zbarmodule.o
    In file included from zbarmodule.c:24:0:
    zbarmodule.h:26:18: fatal error: zbar.h: No such file or directory
     #include <zbar.h>
                      ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/zbar/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-zIuGzw-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install

running build

running build_ext

building 'zbar' extension

creating build

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c zbarmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/zbarmodule.o

In file included from zbarmodule.c:24:0:

zbarmodule.h:26:18: fatal error: zbar.h: No such file or directory

 #include <zbar.h>

                  ^

compilation terminated.

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

So I tried to install the Python zbar binding separately using

Unfortunately I don't even seem to be able to install the zbar package on linux

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install libzbar-dev
sudo pip install zbar
```

It is usually a -dev package that you are missing when you get  those kind of errors, an easy way to find the package is `apt-cache search` like below:

```
~$ apt-cache search zbar
libbarcode-zbar-perl - bar code scanner and decoder (Perl bindings)
libzbar-dev - bar code scanner and decoder (development)
libzbar0 - bar code scanner and decoder (library)
libzbargtk-dev - bar code scanner and decoder (GTK+ bindings development)
libzbargtk0 - bar code scanner and decoder (GTK+ bindings)
libzbarqt-dev - bar code scanner and decoder (Qt bindings development)
libzbarqt0 - bar code scanner and decoder (Qt bindings)
python-qrtools - high level library for reading and generating QR codes
python-zbar - bar code scanner and decoder (Python bindings)
python-zbarpygtk - bar code scanner and decoder (PyGTK bindings)
zbar-dbg - bar code scanner and decoder (debug)
zbar-tools - bar code scanner and decoder (utilities)
```

FWIW, the procedure I used to install was  `python-qrtools`  ,`libzbar-dev`  and finally `pip install zbar`.

Comment: Thanks a million! Just a note about your last line: apt-getting `python-qrtools` IS EQUAL TO apt-getting `zbar-tools`, `libzbar-dev` and `python-zbar`. So the last three replace the first one. But again; thanks a million!

Comment: @kramer65,no worries,  did you not have python-qrtools installed already?  I had to install `libzbar-dev` to remove the error.

Comment: Yes I did have python-qrtools already installed, but I just fired up a couple VMs to try it out on fresh installs.. :). Right now I'm trying to install this on heroku using the heroku-buildpack-apt, at which I fail miserably. I don't want to spam you, but if you also have an idea for my new question I would be extremely grateful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27425981/why-dont-these-apt-packages-behave-the-same-on-ubuntu-and-heroku

Comment: looking at your logs I don't think python-rtools install libzbar-dev, so libzbar-dev  is needed in both cases, do you  have a `zbar.so` file in yor site-packages?

Comment: But if I only install `python-qrtools`, running `import zbar` from the python command line does work. So I guess `libzbar-dev` doesn't seem to be needed..

Comment: have you checked for the zbar.so?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 14.04, without installing `libzbar-dev` I cannot compile zbar with pip, python-rtools installs the zbar bindings only not the developement headers

Comment: I would search for the zbar.so and make sure it is in the path for the interpreter you are using, if not adding the path or copying the .so  will work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66669/discussion-between-kramer65-and-padraic-cunningham).