# Decode Micro QR codes with Python

Tags: python, qr-code

I used "segno" to create Micro QR codes with python:

```
import segno
segno.make_micro("1").save("1.png", scale=10)
```

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fn1Hz.png)

Does anyone know of a (simple) way to decode these with python? I could not find a library but I'm afraid that doning this myself (maybe with openCV) will be much effort.

In contrast to this post ([How to decode a QR-code image in (preferably pure) Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27233351/how-to-decode-a-qr-code-image-in-preferably-pure-python)) I successfully installed PyQRCode and ZBar, already. Unfortunately these libraries do not decode **Micro** QR codes.

Comment: Zxing came to my mind and https://github.com/dlenski/python-zxing, it may be worth a try?

Comment: pyqrcode reference to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27233351/how-to-decode-a-qr-code-image-in-preferably-pure-python

Comment: Unfortunately, still none of them recognize *Micro QR* codes...

Answer (score 3):

[PyBoof](https://pypi.org/project/PyBoof/) just got updated and now supports scanning / reading Micro QR Codes and generating them too. See example code on Github for [detecting](https://github.com/lessthanoptimal/PyBoof/blob/SNAPSHOT/examples/microqr_detect.py) and [creating](https://github.com/lessthanoptimal/PyBoof/blob/v0.40.0/examples/microqr_encode.py). Below is a copy of the code for scanning/detecting:

```
import numpy as np
import pyboof as pb

# Detects all the QR Codes in the image and prints their message and location
data_path = "../data/example/fiducial/microqr/image01.jpg"

detector = pb.FactoryFiducial(np.uint8).microqr()

image = pb.load_single_band(data_path, np.uint8)

detector.detect(image)

print("Detected a total of {} QR Codes".format(len(detector.detections)))

for qr in detector.detections:
    print("Message: " + qr.message)
    print("     at: " + str(qr.bounds))
```

PyBoof is a wrapper around [BoofCV](https://boofcv.org) so you might want to check that out also.

Answer (score 1):

Since [apparently](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/issues/209) using *Micro QR* codes has not become widespread enough (yet?) to merit adding support for reading them in any library I could find, I was looking for a workaround. In my search I came across one or two online QR readers that support decoding micro QR codes. Since I am just learning [Playwright for Python](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-python), I thought, I'd give it a try.

The code below uses `playwright` to open an online QR code decoder website, click through the page to set the correct options, upload the image file and then read the result from the page.

I am aware that this is a completely convoluted way and noone would do this in production code, but it was fun and it *does* work :) Though it does not qualify as "simple" as the OP requested, I'm afraid.

```
from playwright import sync_playwright
import segno

segno.make_micro("1").save("1.png", scale=10)

with sync_playwright() as p:
   browser = p.firefox.launch(headless=False)
   page = browser.newPage()
   page.goto('https://www.datasymbol.com/barcode-reader-sdk/barcode-reader-sdk-for-windows/online-barcode-decoder.html')
   page.querySelector('select[name=\"sr\"]').selectOption([{'label': 'Text'}])
   page.querySelector('img[alt=\"QRCode Decoder Scanner Settings\"]').click()
   page.querySelector('input[name=\"qrmicro\"]').click()
   page.querySelector('input[id=\"fupload1\"]').setInputFiles('1.png')
   page.querySelector('input[type=\"button\"]').click()
   iframe = page.querySelector('iframe[name=\"f2\"]').contentFrame()
   result = iframe.querySelector('css=pre').innerHTML().rstrip()
   print(result)
   browser.close()
```

prints

```
1
```

Some notes:

- if you do not want to see the page during execution, simply delete `headless=False`.
- apparently, there is a pretty unpleasant limitation to using at least the service I chose: if the text you encode is longer than two characters, the website will change the first two characters to `**`, so if you encoded `One Two Three` you will retrieve `**e Two Three`. This is a limitation if you do not create the barcodes yourself. If you do, simply add `**` at the beginning of your contents in the first place.
- if you *do* want to use a remote service but don't want the complex way via the web interface, there are services that offer a direct API you can use e.g. with `requests`. The site I chose above apparently also offers something like that and there seems to be a free plan. But I never used it so I can't say anything about it.