# Is there a way to get only data codeword modules of a qr code in Python?

Tags: python, qr-code

Before a qr code is created , the data to be embedded is converted to binary bits using alphanumeric, utf-8 etc. Then error codewords are added to it and final msg is structured. Is there a way to get **only embedded data codewords modules along with its padding as 0's and 1's** and not error correction codewords , using Python libraries or functions ?

Example:
`HELLO WORLD` if is to be encoded using alphanumeric mode of version 1 qr code, then after its conversion to the mentioned mode and addtion of padding bits it is

```
00100000
01011011
00001011
01111000
11010001
01110010
11011100
01001101
01000011
01000000
11101100
00010001
11101100
```

This is what embedded in qr code using black and white modules after adding error codewords. i need to extract only this data message if its already embedded in a qr code using python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to decode a QR-code image in (preferably pure) Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27233351/how-to-decode-a-qr-code-image-in-preferably-pure-python)

Comment: Thanks Aritesh , but that's not what I m looking for

Comment: @Ruosh Could you show an example of what you're looking for?