# How can I get a QR code from an encrypted image?

Tags: python, qr-code

[This is png image:](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gvYe9mkGFWloSTE4VWpWuehzdzNJ4P6v)

When I open it with Notepad++ I found that this is a QR code 
How to recover it, if python have any lib for this problem?

Comment: why you open a png with notepad++ in first place?

Comment: cause the hint suggest me that. Actually when I open it with a browser I found a base64 code from the sources, decode it and the contend is the same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to decode a QR-code image in (preferably pure) Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27233351/how-to-decode-a-qr-code-image-in-preferably-pure-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say that this is encrypted, more like encoded in such a way that every white pixel should be a numeric character while other characters should appear as black. That's fairly easy to *decode* and then you can use your favorite image building/manipulation library to recreate the image.

Here's an example using the simple [`pypng`](https://pythonhosted.org/pypng/) module:

```
import png

with open("misc.png", "r") as f:  # open the file for reading and...
    # ... read the file line by line and store numbers as white and others as black pixels
    data = [[pixel.isdecimal() for pixel in line] for line in f]
png.from_array(data, "L", {"bitdepth": 1}).save("decoded.png")  # use pypng to save it as PNG
```

Which, for the linked data in `misc.png`, will produce `decoded.png`:

[image]

Comment: oh thank you so much