# install mod_wsgi on mac: error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

Tags: macos, pip, mod-wsgi

I want to run Django project on Apache. So I tried to install mod_wsgi.
I got this error

```
sudo pip3 install mod_wsgi
```

then I got this error

```
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["'cc' failed with exit status 1" error when install python library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697440/cc-failed-with-exit-status-1-error-when-install-python-library)

Answer (score 0):

For macOS you need to have installed both the Xcode application and the Xcode command line tools.

Comment: Aren't you installing the Xcode from the App Store? Did you download it separately somehow?

Comment: Thank you for answering questions. Now I'm downloading the Xcode application. After installing both on my mac, I will try again. Thanks again.

Comment: Just make sure you startup Xcode app once as it installs stuff the first time it is run. Then separately install xcode command line tools.

Comment: Hi, Graham Dumpleton, It works. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi, Graham, I have some other issue installing mod_wsgi. Where can I find mod_wsgi.so file when I install mod_wsgi using pip?

Comment: Run ``mod_wsgi-express module-config`` and it will give you the config to put in Apache if doing it manually. Run ``mod_wsgi-express module-location`` if just want to know where ``.so`` file is.