# Cant complete mysql-python installation in OSX

Tags: python, mysql, macos, pip, clang

I have tried to get this to work, but I have had no success. I'm trying to install `mysql-python` by running :

```
pip install mysql-python
```

but I always get this error

```
clang: error: invalid version number in '-mmacosx-version-min=10.11'
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

I have used homebrew to update all libraries and I have already installed mysql. I also made sure to have the latest pip, xcode and xcode command line tools.

I have searched for hours but I have not found a way get this package to build.

Please, if anyone has run into a similar situation, I would greatly appreciate a little bit of guidance.

```
Collecting mysql-python
Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
Building wheels for collected packages: mysql-python
Running setup.py bdist_wheel for mysql-python ... error
Complete output from command /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/qh/38cj02sj1fb83lfnsd4x3jm40000gn/T/pip-build-lCuswO/mysql-python/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /var/folders/qh/38cj02sj1fb83lfnsd4x3jm40000gn/T/tmpFVHSn1pip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7
copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7
creating build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
creating build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.12/include/mysql -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o -fno-omit-frame-pointer
clang: error: invalid version number in '-mmacosx-version-min=10.11'
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: What is the version of OSX you are using?

Comment: El Capitan 10.11.4

Comment: Can you post the complete traceback?

Comment: I would love to share it, but I will not fit on this comment field as I only have about 600 characters I can add here, Any other ideas on how I could share this

Comment: You can [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37129088/edit) and add it.

Answer (score 3):

This might be because x-code is not installed

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: Use this incase x-code is installed:
sudo xcode-select --reset

Answer (score 0):

You should install MySQL through Homebrew first, to get python-mysql work properly on OS X.

```
pip uninstall MySQL-python
brew install mysql
brew install mysql-connector-c
pip install MySQL-python
```

Original answer : [MySQL-python on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17847170/2142994)

Comment: Hey Ani! thanks so much for your response. I did those already, no luck. Still gives the same error.

Comment: I tried the edited version and still no good. I keep getting that clang error. Thanks for your help though.

Any other ideas?  Thanks in advance

Comment: Tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22413050/cant-install-python-mysql-library-on-mac-mavericks)? Alse check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22697917/2142994).

Comment: I just did, I got the exact same output

clang: error: invalid version number in '-mmacosx-version-min=10.11'
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1