# Install blist in mac os x Mavericks

Tags: python, macos, clang

When I installed the [blist](http://stutzbachenterprises.com/blist/) on my mac (OS X Mavericks 10.9.2) I confronted error

```
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -DBLIST_FLOAT_RADIX_SORT=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _blist.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/_blist.o

clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]

clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future

error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

Clang version:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on github [ticket](https://github.com/DanielStutzbach/blist/issues/65#issuecomment-37978953) and this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22322645/102668), following worked for me.

```
sudo su
export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
pip install blist
```

Answer (score 1):

I found workaround for this problem.

Install apple-gcc42 (for Homebrew use next command):

```
$brew install apple-gcc42
```

Than change symlink for /usr/bin/cc

```
$ls -al /usr/bin/cc
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  5 Feb 25 11:11 cc -> clang
```

with command

```
$cd /usr/bin
$sudo ln -sf /usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/gcc-4.2 cc

$ls -al /usr/bin/cc
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  54 Mar 18 12:50 cc -> /usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/gcc-4.2
```

where "/usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/gcc-4.2" path where Homebrew install package with apple-gcc42 compiler.

Then install blist.

If you find better solution please post it.