# Python virtualenv pip install MySQL-Python causing "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded"

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, mysql-python

I setup a virtualenv and then tried to install `MySQL-Python` using pip (`after activating env`). My `requirements.txt` is as following:

```
MySQL-python==1.2.5
argparse==1.2.1
pymongo==2.6.3
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

When I run `pip install -r requirement.txt`. I get some output last line of which is:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

As mentioned in a post, I even ran this command to upgrade my distribute:

```
easy_install distribute==0.6.28
```

Even that didn't work. My python version (in env) is 2.7.6 and Machine is Ubuntu 14.04

---

**UPDATE**:   Stack trace is as following:

```
Downloading/unpacking MySQL-python==1.2.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Running setup.py (path:/root/frrole_backend_raw_dump/env/build/MySQL-python/setup.py) egg_info for package MySQL-python
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/root/frrole_backend_raw_dump/env/build/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 21, in <module>
        setuptools.setup(**metadata)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 112, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 225, in __init__
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 287, in __init__
        self.finalize_options()
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 257, in finalize_options
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2029, in require
        self.name = name
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 580, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 825, in best_match
        ``installer(requirement)``, unless `installer` is None, in which case
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 837, in obtain
        def __iadd__(self, other):
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 272, in fetch_build_egg
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 225, in __init__
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 287, in __init__
        self.finalize_options()
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 257, in finalize_options
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2029, in require
        self.name = name
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 580, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 825, in best_match
        ``installer(requirement)``, unless `installer` is None, in which case
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 837, in obtain
        def __iadd__(self, other):
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 272, in fetch_build_egg
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 225, in __init__
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 287, in __init__
        self.finalize_options()
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 257, in finalize_options
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2029, in require
        self.name = name
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 580, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 825, in best_match
        ``installer(requirement)``, unless `installer` is None, in which case
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 837, in obtain
        def __iadd__(self, other):
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 272, in fetch_build_egg
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 225, in __init__
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 287, in __init__
        self.finalize_options()
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 257, in finalize_options
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2029, in require
        self.name = name
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 580, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
```

Comment: Please post the complete traceback.

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same issue.  @BurhanKhalid since it's an infinite loop most of the traceback is just more of the above.  I'll let the OP edit the question to add  the tail end of it.

Answer (score 4):

Getting this too!

Some notes from my setup:

- Ubuntu 13.10

  - Python-MySQLdb and libmysqlclient-dev are both installed via apt-get

I also see this, which I suspect is the root cause:

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Qunused-arguments’
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Qunused-arguments’
```

**EDIT:**

Looks like I still get this (MySQL-Python 1.2.4) without a CFLAGS or CPPFLAGS environment variable set. **1.2.5 works for me**.

Comment: lololol, Thought those flags looked familiar :) My issue was a modification I made to my .bashrc as per [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/clang-error-unknown-argument-mno-fused-madd-python-package-installation-fa) on my Mac. I copied my .bashrc over from that machine.