# can not install psycopg2 2.5+ on mac osx 10.9

Tags: python, macos

Here is the error log:

```
building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension

creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7

creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/psycopg

cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090301 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I. -I/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/include -I/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o

clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]

clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future

error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

Any suggestions? any workaround? I am entirely blocked by this for about a day.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This one works for me:

export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments

[clang error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' (python package installation failure)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/clang-error-unknown-argument-mno-fused-madd-python-package-installation-fa)

Comment: This resolves issues I was having on OSX 10.9. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

sudo ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install psycopg2

Comment: Thanks, this one worked where the other answers failed!

Answer (score 1):

Im pretty sure pyscopg2 doesnt support 9.3 yet. Here's the documentation http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/news.html

I see references for 9.1 and 9.2 but nothing for 9.3 especially since it was just released a few months ago. 9.3 incorporates it's own  Foreign Writable wrapper which other modules like Multicorn now utilize.

http://www.postgresql.org/about/news/1481/

I could be wrong, just a possibility. Try using 9.2 and see if it works.

Comment: 9.3 was released a while ago I believe.