# Cython Installation Error on Os X

Tags: python, macos, pip, osx-mavericks, cython

I tried to install Cython with pip, easy_install and from source code. And I am taking following error on OsX Maverics:

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]

clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future

error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

I am using `Python 2.7.5`

```
pip version 1.4.1
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/clang-error-unknown-argument-mno-fused-madd-python-package-installation-fa

Answer (score 5):

This is an issue with Mavericks. You can circumvent this as follows:

Terminal:

```
sudo CFLAGS=-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install cython
```

This will suppress the errors as warnings, allowing you to install cython.