# Installing psycopg2 using Flask/Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, psycopg2

I've been searching all night for a solution to this, but I seem to be running into an uncommon error while trying to install psycopg2 in a virtualenv on a Flask application. I run this command:

> pip install
>   http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/psycopg2/psycopg2-2.4.tar.gz

This is the error:

> creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/psycopg
>
> cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386
>   -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.4 (dt dec pq3 ext)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090104 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1
>   -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7
>   -I. -I/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/include -I/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/include/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o
>   build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o
>
> clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd'
>   [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
>
> clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a
>   warning) in the future
>
> error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
>
> ---------------------------------------- Command /Users/jasdeep1/Dropbox/workspace/Printbase/venv/bin/python -c "import
>   setuptools;**file**='/var/folders/9q/bg9_hgr16s7gt7gdbg8x79wr0000gn/T/pip-TbS4xF-build/setup.py';exec(compile(open(**file**).read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record
>   /var/folders/9q/bg9_hgr16s7gt7gdbg8x79wr0000gn/T/pip-Yavgs4-record/install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /Users/jasdeep1/Dropbox/workspace/Printbase/venv/include/site/python2.7
>   failed with error code 1 in
>   /var/folders/9q/bg9_hgr16s7gt7gdbg8x79wr0000gn/T/pip-TbS4xF-build
>   Storing complete log in /Users/jasdeep1/.pip/pip.log

Not exactly sure how to solve for this. No answers I've seen seem to address this. Any help stepping in the right direction is appreciated.

Happy to share more of the debug output, but wasn't sure how much detail is too much detail.

Comment: Try the solution to this question, very similar to yours - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407

Comment: possible duplicate of [clang error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' (python package installation failure)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/clang-error-unknown-argument-mno-fused-madd-python-package-installation-fa)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to install `psycopg2` directly from pip -- not sure why you're installing the tarball manually (although, it should work assuming you already have `libpq-dev` and `build-essential` install ).

```
$ pip install -U psycopg2
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing: Open terminal (editor or local)

```
$ brew install postgresql
$ brew services start postgresql
```

And go to sql promp for create a db (don't leave terminal):

```
$ psql postgres
```

> `CREATE DATABASE ..`
> `CREATE USER`
> `GRANT ...`

And Connection Sample:

```
def con_db():
    conn = None
    cursor = None

    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect("host= dbname= user= password=")

        cursor = conn.cursor()
        sql_query = """select .."""
        cursor.execute(sql_query)

        # conn.commit()
        result = cursor.fetchall()  # fetchone()

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
```