# installing lxml in OSX 10.9

Tags: python, macos, lxml, osx-mavericks

I have a problem installing the `lxml` in my mavericks machine.

I tried all possibilities by installing the prebuild binaries using

- normal pip
- pip with `static deps`

and Building

- Current version in normal model
- Current version with static deps
- Older version in normal mode
- Older version with static deps

and always end up in this error.

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

here the detailed message

```
copying /Users/mangoreader/work/lxml-3.3.4/build/tmp/libxml2/include/libxslt/xsltutils.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/lxml/includes/libxslt
running build_ext
building 'lxml.etree' extension
cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -I/Users/mangoreader/work/lxml-3.3.4/build/tmp/libxml2/include -I/Users/mangoreader/work/lxml-3.3.4/build/tmp/libxml2/include/libxml2 -I/Users/mangoreader/work/lxml-3.3.4/build/tmp/libxml2/include/libxslt -I/Users/mangoreader/work/lxml-3.3.4/build/tmp/libxml2/include/libexslt -I/Users/mangoreader/work/lxml-3.3.4/src/lxml/includes -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w -flat_namespace
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

Also when i tried installing `cython` , i am getting the same error

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]

clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future

error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

detailed log here

```
cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c /private/var/folders/1z/7lv1qq457qxbhkgpt1fk9sdc0000gn/T/pip_build_mangoreader/cython/Cython/Plex/Scanners.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/private/var/folders/1z/7lv1qq457qxbhkgpt1fk9sdc0000gn/T/pip_build_mangoreader/cython/Cython/Plex/Scanners.o

clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]

clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future

error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/1z/7lv1qq457qxbhkgpt1fk9sdc0000gn/T/pip_build_mangoreader/cython/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/1z/7lv1qq457qxbhkgpt1fk9sdc0000gn/T/pip-0akrMB-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/1z/7lv1qq457qxbhkgpt1fk9sdc0000gn/T/pip_build_mangoreader/cython
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/mangoreader/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

I am totally struck here. It seems this is something to do with the version conflict with gcc or libxml. But i could't figure out what. Any help much appreciated.

**SOLVED**

As per this SO post [clang error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' (python package installation failure)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/clang-error-unknown-argument-mno-fused-madd-python-package-installation-fa?rq=1), this can be fixed by setting up this following env variables

```
export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that by that that you sorted it out, but in case someone else needs it, install XCode and command line tools and just run

```
pip install lxml
```

It will work, may take a little time.