# ImportError when installing newspaper

Tags: python, importerror, python-newspaper

I am pretty new to python and am trying to import newspaper for article extraction. Whenever I try to import the module I get `ImportError: cannot import name images`. Anyone come across this problem and found a solution?

Answer (score 6):

I was able to fix this problem by creating an `images` directory in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/newspaper` , moving `images.py` to this directory, and placing a blank `__init__.py` in this directory.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a dated entry, but to anyone else that faced the same issue as me, I initially fumbled with resolving this issue. When I first run `import newspaper`, I faced this error. `lxml runtime error: Reason: Incompatible library version: etree.so requires version 12.0.0 or later, but libxml2.2.dylib provides version 10.0.0`

When I tried to re-run my code (without correcting anything), I got the error found on this article. I have no idea why this was the case, and I wasn't able to resolve my issue using the above method (it didn't work for me, but it could still work for you). If anyone was fumbling like me on Jupyter on getting `newspaper` to work, do consider the link below. Hope this is helpful.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31607751/6143792