# Python import error on one machine, but not on the other

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, python-newspaper

I'm using a library called [newspaper](https://github.com/codelucas/newspaper/tree/python-2-head) and deploying my app to elastic beanstalk. It runs fine locally, but on the server it doesn't work and throws this error:

```
File "/opt/python/current/app/application.py", line 7, in <module>
  from api.v01.api import apiv01
File "/opt/python/current/app/api/v01/api.py", line 19, in <module>
  from newspaper import Article
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newspaper/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
  from .article import Article, ArticleException
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newspaper/article.py", line 12, in <module>
  from . import images
ImportError: cannot import name images
```

Both machines are running python 2.7.9.
What could the problem be?

Just to confirm, I'm using requirements.txt to load the dependencies, and they are loaded fine on both machines.

Comment: did you install `newspaper` package on your server?

Comment: @Nhor yes. You can tell because if I had't it wouldn't show me lines 5-8 above!

Comment: have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28036292/importerror-when-installing-newspaper

Comment: That's not a good answer for a number of reasons - it doesn't explain why it works locally but not on eb; it doesn't allow me to solve the problem with scale (when nw machines are fired up i don't want to have to do this each time); and finally I don't want to be editing dependencies manually.

Comment: Have you checked file permissions on the server?

Comment: @jcfollower Nope, which files should i check the permissions for and is there anything in particular I should be looking for?

Comment: I don't know newspaper, but  I would say that you should make sure that whatever user django is running as has permissions to read whatever file the images class is in.