# Error when importing newspaper module

Tags: python, python-newspaper

I'm trying to use the newspaper package on python 2 and I keep getting the error `cannot import name images` error when I download it.

I followed previous SO advice and created an image directory in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newspaper` with the `images.py` and `__init__.py` files but it still doesn't work: 
  [ImportError when installing newspaper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28036292/importerror-when-installing-newspaper)

The only difference between that advice and what I implemented is that I have `site-packages` instead of `dist-packages`. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you installing via pip and PyPI?

Answer (score 1):

`Newspaper` has been deprecated for Python2 and it's a buggy version according to their official [documentation](https://github.com/codelucas/newspaper). You should switch to Python3 version.

Installation on Python 3:

```
pip3 install newspaper3k
```

*Newspaper is a Python3 library! Or, view our deprecated and buggy Python2 branch. Run : `pip3 install newspaper3k`  and NOT `pip3 install newspaper`.
On python3 you must install newspaper3k, not newspaper. newspaper is our python2 library. Although installing newspaper is simple with pip, you will run into fixable issues if you are trying to install on ubuntu.*