# Incompatible version of library libxml2.2.dylib in python OSX 10.10.5

Tags: python, macos, osx-yosemite, anaconda

I am trying to use the `louvain` python library after it was successfully installed. However, when I tried to load it, the interpreter says

```
>>> import louvain
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/louvain/__init__.py", line 108, in <module>
    from .functions import find_partition
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/louvain/functions.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import _c_louvain
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/louvain/_c_louvain.so, 2): Library not loaded: libxml2.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/louvain/_c_louvain.so
  Reason: Incompatible library version: _c_louvain.so requires version 12.0.0 or later, but libxml2.2.dylib provides version 10.0.0
```

I have found a similar thread in this issue [lxlm run time error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23172384/lxml-runtime-error-reason-incompatible-library-version-etree-so-requires-vers). However, when I tied the proposed solution (i.e., force to install libxml2) `conda install -f libxml2` it install it but I cannot load the louvain library. Basically, it generates the same error. I have the `Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (x86_64)| (default, Sep 15 2015, 14:29:08)` version. Do you have any suggestion? Thanks in advance.