# Issues with scrapy and anaconda

Tags: python, scrapy, anaconda

I'm trying to get scrapy installed and working. I have anaconda installed so I deleted the path to python 3.5 from my bash profile but I still get this error. All my dependencies are up to date, including lxml, but I get this when I try to start a project in scrapy.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 7, in <module>
    from scrapy.cmdline import execute
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from scrapy.spiders import Spider
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scrapy.http import Request
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/http/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from scrapy.http.request.form import FormRequest
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/form.py", line 9, in <module>
    import lxml.html
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from .. import etree
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so, 2):            Library not loaded: libxml2.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so
  Reason: Incompatible library version: etree.so requires version 12.0.0 or later, but libxml2.2.dylib provides version 10.0.0
```

Comment: try `conda install -c scrapinghub scrapy`.

Comment: Answer that worked for me is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23172384/lxml-runtime-error-reason-incompatible-library-version-etree-so-requires-vers