# Python error message "Incompatible library version" libxml and etree.so

Tags: python, virtualenv, libxml2

**Update 2:**

the main problem turned out to be a different one from what I had thought it was, and asked for help here. I moved the new question to a new post:

[Install custom python package in virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37355662/install-custom-python-package-in-virtualenv)

---

**Update:**
ok, so I screwed up my non-virtualenv by accident.
The non-virtualenv (normal bash) I could easily fix by removing the manually installed (via pip) lxml and running

```
conda install lxml --force
```

But for some reason, that doesn't work in the virtualenv.
There, running

```
    conda install lxml --force
```

works without error message, but when I run python and simply say

```
>>> import lxml
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named lxml
```

Any suggestions??

---

**old message:**

I'm trying to use virtualenv for my python flask application.
The python code runs perfectly fine without the virtualenv.

I've installed the packages I need in the virtualenv, but I after installing lxml via

```
pip install lxml
Installing collected packages: lxml
Successfully installed lxml-3.6.0
```

I get the following error message when running my code:

```
  File "/Users/XXX/xxx/flask-aws/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docx-0.2.4-py2.7.egg/docx.py", line 17, in <module>
from lxml import etree

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/XXX/xxx/flask-aws/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so, 2): Library not loaded: libxml2.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/XXX/xxx/flask-aws/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so

  Reason: Incompatible library version: etree.so requires version 12.0.0 or later, but libxml2.2.dylib provides version 10.0.0
```

I have seen other people report similar problems at stackoverflow, and one guy remarked that the problem might related to the virtualenv, but there was no solution.

Once again: The python code runs perfectly **fine without virtualenv**! But inside virtualenv, I can't get it to work.

I'm using Anaconda Python 2.7 on a Mac.

I'd appreciate any help guys!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25435087/3103677 Did you look at this?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, as I wrote above, it didn't work, though in the virtualenv.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same error and stumbled upon this [link](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/2446), after searching for the incompatible library error "libxml2.2.dylib provides version 10.0.0"

Installing libxml2 that worked for me:

```
brew install libxml2 
brew link --force libxml2
```

Comment: I also had to force the install:
    `brew install --force libxml2`

Answer (score 0):

Solution that works for me in virtual environment is to force `pip` to recompile `lxml`:

```
pip install lxml --force-reinstall --ignore-installed --no-binary :all:
```