# Install custom python package in virtualenv

Tags: python, macos, amazon-web-services, virtualenv

I want to deploy a python flask app using Amazon’s Elastic Beanstalk.
Therefore, I want to use virtualenv to make sure to get the right packages.

However, one package (docx) isn't available through pip and I'd like to install it manually.
If I do install it manually via `python setup.py install` the installation works, but the package screws up lxml dependencies.

1. Do I need the virtualenv in the first place, or can I also just log into the amazon console and install all packages manually?
2. I'm running a Mac at home, and linux on amazon's S3 server, so can building the package on my Mac (I think some c-code is compiled) work anyway?
3. If you do recommend to still use virtualenv, any idea of how to resolve the screwed up library issue above?
   (if I am outside of the virtualenv and use `conda install lxml`, I'm good. But inside of virtualenv, `conda install lxml` will *not* install lxml for some reason, `import lxml` gives an error that the library isn't found.

I'd appreciate your input.

Comment: The answer to question #2 is definitely no.

Comment: fwiw, also on OSX. I had the gnarliest issues getting lxml to install onto an Ubuntu VM.  My end take was that I only needed for some unittesting package and I didn't, strictly speaking, so much need to run tests **on** the VM as **against** the VM.  So I left it out.  But I got the impression lxml is unusually brittle with regards to its installation and the underlying OS/distribution.

Comment: Have you installed all the dependencies for lxml???