# "clang: error: unknown argument" with Google Analytics

Tags: objective-c, xcode, google-analytics, ios7.1, xcode5.1

After updating to Xcode 5.1, I am having a compile time fatal error on my project that I am not fully understanding.

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-force_load GoogleAnalyticsServices' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
```

Is this a hard error because `-force_load` is no longer needed in 5.1, or is there something I'm overlooking (e.g. spelling error, missing file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/clang-error-unknown-argument-mno-fused-madd-python-package-installation-fa/22372751#22372751

Comment: So why is `-force_load` is no longer needed in 5.1?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `-force_load GoogleAnalyticsServices` from your target Build Settings' `OTHER_LDFLAGS` (Other Linker Flags).

You can also just search for `GoogleAnalyticsServices` in the same window.

Comment: I'm pretty sure yu can remove it in both. Why would you use 5.0 and not 5.1? ;)

Comment: what I'm asking is, why would it need to be there in 5.0, but is safe to remove in 5.1? I know deleting it makes the error go away, but so does wiping out all my files and having a blank project.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 5 caused clang to throw a fatal error when it encountered an unknown command line flag, which broke a lot of things.

Add this to your `ARCHFLAGS` flags in Xcode. `-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future`

Comment: Doesn't this just suppress the error, rather than solve the problem?

Comment: @JoeCortopassi if the problem is with upstream libraries, I prefer to suppress it and leave the fixing of the problem to them. Note that the 5.1 change just changed that from a warning to an exception–so the code was invalid in the first place. I would add this to your arch flags and put in a issue with the library maintainers.

Comment: @justin Punting the issue to the library maintainer doesn't mean my code is any better. Just hides the actual problem

Answer (score 0):

From my investigation it seems as if you have added single quotes around the value of `Other Linker Flags` in your project's `Build Settings`.

Xcode is then trying to interpret the entire line as a flag/argument.

Try removing the quotes, if they exist