# Installing Mezzanine

Tags: django, mezzanine

I'm trying to install mezzanine on Mac using Maverick by running:

```
$sudo pip install mezzanine
```

When I receive the error:

```
$clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd'
  [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]

$clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning)
 in the future

$error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

---

```
$Cleaning up...
$Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools,$tokenize;
  __file__='/private/tmp/pip_build_root/pillow/setup.py';
  exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)    (__file__).read().replace(
 '\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))"
  install --record /tmp/pip-QoV_TT-record/install-record.txt 
   --single-version-externally-managed 
  --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip_build_root/pillow
```

I installed xcode developer tools because I thought that was my problem, but I'm still stuck here. Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/clang-error-unknown-argument-mno-fused-madd-python-package-installation-fa?lq=1 other than the actual package being installed.