# Updating numpy on MacOS X

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to update numpy from version 1.6.2 to 1.8.1. My first attempt was to do

```
sudo pip uninstall numpy
```

and then install it again with pip. But when I check the version I get the old one:

```
import numpy as np
np.__version__
'1.6.2'
```

Then, I tried to

```
sudo easy_install -U numpy
```

but I get an error:
    RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program

The path to the numpy version I use is: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy

So, is the solution to manually install (from source) the desired version of Numpy or is there a way to use pip or easy_install?

Comment: Do you have developer tools for XCode installed?

Comment: @favoretti, yes I do.

Comment: go to the log file and paste it somewhere, usually there are enough detail there, then we can help.

Comment: I guess it can't find your C compiler for some reason.

Comment: The error you're getting means that pip can't find your compiler indeed. What would `which gcc` say?

Comment: @favoretti if I do `which gcc` I get `/usr/bin/gcc`

Comment: Have you tried compiling numpy manually? The only thing you need to do (other than make/make install) is to make sure it's compiled as a framework.

Comment: Also, I'd very much recommend using brew (http://brew.sh/), since it often contains patches that are MacOSX specific.

Comment: Have you looked into Anaconda or Canopy? Unless you have a specific need to build from source, using a distribution is by far the easiest option.

Comment: @MrE you are right, I was trying to avoid Canopy but when you need quick results, it's the easiest way to keep all the packages accessible and updated.

Comment: Check the fix here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/clang-error-unknown-argument-mno-fused-madd-python-package-installation-fa