# clang throwing error for unknown command

Tags: python, xcode, clang, osx-mavericks

I am trying to setup dev environment for my new maverick 10.9.3.I've installed Xcode 5.1.1 with command line utility. I'm trying to run buildout with Python 2.4 application. Every time it stuck at same point. I googled and found different answers about this problem and tried most. i.e. setting environment variables and all but doesn't seems to be working.

Any idea or suggestion will be great help and Thanks for taking time for it.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [clang error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' (python package installation failure)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/clang-error-unknown-argument-mno-fused-madd-python-package-installation-fa)

Comment: I tried it. Doesnt look like it's working for me.

Comment: Your question isn't very explicit about what you've tried. The screenshot(!) sure makes it look like it's a matter of the `-mno-fused-madd` option. Do you have any control over the options? Moreover, have you looked into the warning about the missing directory?

Comment: Thanks for reply. what do you mean by options ? I tried to set some variable via export but doesn't make any difference. I haven't looked into missing directory issue yet. I am trying this to local computer with sudo. btw, I am trying to install buildout file.

Comment: By "options" I mean the command line options to Clang. How did you export the variables, and did you confirm somehow that they were set correctly?

Comment: OK, I tried to echo them to confirm.