# Can't install lxml on OS X 10.8.5

Tags: python, macos, lxml, libxml2, malware

I'm trying to do a malware analysis by using cuckoo sandbox and a VM Machine (WinXP) running on VirtualBox. But however, I can't get cuckoo to run because I haven't installed cybox and maec correctly.

Thus leads me to this problem where I can't get myself to install lxml. 
It just won't let me install either by using pip or manual installation with the setup.py file. 
Here is what I got:

```
Building lxml version 3.4.1.
Building without Cython.
Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.26
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing requirements to src/lxml.egg-info/requires.txt
writing src/lxml.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to src/lxml.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to src/lxml.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'src/lxml.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'src/lxml.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
copying src/lxml/includes/lxml-version.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/lxml/includes
running build_ext
building 'lxml.etree' extension
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/Users/ajprameswari/Downloads/lxml-3.4.1/src/lxml/includes -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w -flat_namespace
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

I tried both lxml-3.4.0 and lxml-3.4.1 version but they gave the same result. 
I'm using Python 2.7 and OS X 10.8.5. Is there anything that could be pointed to help me solve this issue? I'm a newbie in using OS X, I used to work on my Ubuntu, but due to lack spec of my Ubuntu machine I need to work here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/clang-error-unknown-argument-mno-fused-madd-python-package-installation-fa

Comment: thank you for pointing this to a solution! sorry if this was a double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apple LLVM compiler in Xcode 5.1 treats unrecognized command-line options as errors. This issue has been seen when building Python native extensions, where some invalid compiler options are specified.

It seems that the newer version of the llvm compiler shipping is a little more restrictive when it comes to warnings.

**Fix**:
There is a temporary solution to tell the compiler not to raise this error by setting the following environment variables :

```
sudo -E export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
sudo -E export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
```