# PyAMG fails to install on mac

Tags: python, macos, numpy, pip

I'm not able to install PyAMG via pip on OSX 10.8.5. I already have XCode 5.1.1 with it's command line tools installed from within, scipy, numpy and nose. Hope there is a way to fix this. Here is the error I get from the terminal (not a full log), it seems to be related to numpy:

```
copying pyamg/vis/vtk_writer.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/pyamg/vis
running build_ext
customize UnixCCompiler
customize UnixCCompiler using build_ext
customize UnixCCompiler
#### ['clang', '-fno-strict-aliasing', '-fno-common', '-dynamic', '-g', '-Os', '-pipe', '-fno-common', '-fno-strict-aliasing', '-fwrapv', '-mno-fused-madd', '-DENABLE_DTRACE', '-DMACOSX', '-DNDEBUG', '-Wall', '-Wstrict-prototypes', '-Wshorten-64-to-32', '-DNDEBUG', '-g', '-Os', '-Wall', '-Wstrict-prototypes', '-DENABLE_DTRACE', '-arch', 'i386', '-arch', 'x86_64'] #######
Missing compiler_cxx fix for UnixCCompiler
customize UnixCCompiler using build_ext
building 'pyamg.amg_core._amg_core' extension
compiling C++ sources
C compiler: clang++ -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe

creating build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7
creating build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/pyamg
creating build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/pyamg/amg_core
compile options: '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c'
clang++: pyamg/amg_core/amg_core_wrap.cxx
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
error: Command "clang++ -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS=1 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c pyamg/amg_core/amg_core_wrap.cxx -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/pyamg/amg_core/amg_core_wrap.o" failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-YEr4op/pyamg/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-YZbrch-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-YEr4op/pyamg
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/clang-error-unknown-argument-mno-fused-madd-python-package-installation-fa

Comment: I executed these two export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments and then ran the pip install but still get the same error! :(

Comment: Wow that worked! Thanks a lot! I forgot the -E flag!