# Installing flask-bcrypt

Tags: python, flask, installation, pip

I am trying to install flask-bcrypt using
    pip install flask-bcrypt

but I keep getting the following error

```
Collecting cffi>=1.1 (from bcrypt->flask-bcrypt)
Using cached cffi-1.3.1.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory

    No working compiler found, or bogus compiler options
    passed to the compiler from Python's distutils module.
    See the error messages above.
    (If they are about -mno-fused-madd and you are on OS/X 10.8,
    see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/ .)

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-dGKCUD/cffi
```

Any idea how to install it successfully?

Answer (score 1):

You may need the development libraries,

Try either

```
apt-get install build-essential
apt-get install python-devel
```

or

```
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
yum install python-devel
```

Whichever is appropriate.