# can't install cffi on fedora23 workstation

Tags: python, fedora, python-cffi, libffi

I'm Trying to install cffi on fedora23 workstation using pip3.
but m getting following error.

```
pip3 install cffi

Collecting cffi

  Using cached cffi-1.4.2.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libffi' found
Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libffi' found
Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libffi' found
Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libffi' found
Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libffi' found
gcc: error: /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1: No such file or directory
gcc: error: /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1: No such file or directory

    No working compiler found, or bogus compiler options
    passed to the compiler from Python's distutils module.
    See the error messages above.
    (If they are about -mno-fused-madd and you are on OS/X 10.8,
    see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/ .)

----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-yweqr7c9/cffi

What should I do?
Thankx in advance.

Comment: It is the fresh installation. I haven't installed anything else yet.

Comment: Make sure you `dnf install libffi-devel` before running `pip`.  Also you may want to make sure you have `gcc` installed.

Comment: thanx @TomTromey that worked for me.

Comment: Since there is an answer to the question, you could post it as answer and mark it as accepted. The author of the question can also do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments by Tom, you have to install some dependencies before you can compile cffi. However, `libffi-devel` alone wasn't enough in my case, redhat-hardened-cc1 as part of `redhat-rpm-config` was also required. You can install them with

```
sudo dnf install libffi-devel redhat-rpm-config
```

Now you can run `pip3 install cffi` again and it should all compile.