# Buildozer - requirement pysftp

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, buildozer

I'm able to use pysftp on kivy, but I can't package my app using this requirement. Using buildozer, in the message says I'm using pip 8.1.1 and there is another version, 8.1.2. But I checked my version and my one already is 8.1.2. And, of course, I can install pysftp using pip install pysftp. My log file is this:

`# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Programa de gerenciamento de pacotes Debian 'dpkg' versão 1.17.5 (amd64).
Isto é software livre; veja a GNU General Public License versão 2 ou
posterior para condições de cópia. Não existe NENHUMA garantia.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /usr/local/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Apache ANT found at /home/awulll/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /home/awulll/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20
# Android NDK found at /home/awulll/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c
# Check application requirements
# Run './distribute.sh -l'
# Cwd /home/awulll/dapapp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
Available modules: android apsw audiostream bidi boost cherrypy c_igraph click cprotobuf cymunk django docutils ecdsa enum34 evdev ffmpeg ffmpeg2 ffpyplayer ffpyplayer_tito flask freetype gevent greenlet harfbuzz hostpython igraph itsdangerous jinja2 jpeg kivent_core kivent_cymunk kivy leveldb libevent libpq libsodium libswift libtorrent libxml2 libxslt libyaml lxml m2crypto markupsafe midistream msgpack mysql_connector netifaces numpy opencv openssl paramiko pil plyer plyvel png polygon protobuf psutil psycopg2 pyasn1 pycrypto pygame pyjnius pylibpd pyopenssl pyparsing pyqrcode python pyyaml sdl setuptools six sqlalchemy sqlite3 storm swift thrift twisted txws werkzeug wokkel zeroconf zope
# Remove directory and subdirectory /home/awulll/dapapp/.buildozer/applibs
# Create directory /home/awulll/dapapp/.buildozer/applibs
# Run 'bash -c "source venv/bin/activate && env"'
# Cwd /home/awulll/dapapp/.buildozer
XDG_VTNR=8
XDG_SESSION_ID=c1
SSH_AGENT_PID=2191
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/keyring-JXgOZD/gpg:0:1
VTE_VERSION=3409
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm
XDG_SESSION_COOKIE=9cf5cdba17a429f4e3205d8a54ac9c66-1463226321.499664-1491359051
GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT=stderr
WINDOWID=39845895
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/run/user/1000/keyring-JXgOZD
GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS=JS ERROR;JS LOG
USER=awulll
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring-JXgOZD/ssh
SESSION_MANAGER=local/awulll-mint:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2054,unix/awulll-mint:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2054
USERNAME=awulll
DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/default.default.path
VIRTUAL_ENV=/home/awulll/dapapp/.buildozer/venv
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-default:/etc/xdg
PATH=/home/awulll/dapapp/.buildozer/venv/bin:/home/awulll/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/awulll/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin://usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
DESKTOP_SESSION=default
ANDROIDAPI=19
GDM_XSERVER_LOCATION=local
PWD=/home/awulll/dapapp/.buildozer
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
LANG=pt_BR.UTF-8
GNOME_KEYRING_PID=1978
MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/default.mandatory.path
ANDROIDNDK=/home/awulll/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c
PS1=(venv) 
MDM_XSERVER_LOCATION=local
GDMSESSION=default
PACKAGES_PATH=/home/awulll/.buildozer/android/packages
CINNAMON_VERSION=2.4.8
HOME=/home/awulll
SHLVL=2
XDG_SEAT=seat0
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=default
ANDROIDSDK=/home/awulll/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20
LOGNAME=awulll
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/default:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/usr/share/mdm/
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-fdxlKZ9y2o,guid=226dcf0498f8da9740aa1f9157370fd2
MDMSESSION=default
ANDROIDNDKVER=r9c
WINDOWPATH=8
TEXTDOMAIN=im-config
DISPLAY=:0
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
MDM_LANG=pt_BR.UTF-8
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=X-Cinnamon
TEXTDOMAINDIR=/usr/share/locale/
XAUTHORITY=/home/awulll/.Xauthority
COLORTERM=gnome-terminal
_=/usr/bin/env
# Install distribute
# Run 'curl http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py | venv/bin/python'
# Cwd /home/awulll/dapapp/.buildozer
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
# Install requirement datetime in virtualenv
# Run 'pip install --target=/home/awulll/dapapp/.buildozer/applibs datetime'
# Cwd /home/awulll/dapapp/.buildozer
Collecting datetime
/home/awulll/dapapp/.buildozer/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:315: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
/home/awulll/dapapp/.buildozer/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:120: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
Collecting zope.interface (from datetime)
Collecting pytz (from datetime)
  Using cached pytz-2016.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting setuptools (from zope.interface->datetime)
  Using cached setuptools-21.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: setuptools, zope.interface, pytz, datetime
Successfully installed datetime pytz setuptools-20.9.0 zope.interface
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
# Install distribute
# Run 'curl http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py | venv/bin/python'
# Cwd /home/awulll/dapapp/.buildozer
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
# Install requirement pysftp in virtualenv
# Run 'pip install --target=/home/awulll/dapapp/.buildozer/applibs pysftp'
# Cwd /home/awulll/dapapp/.buildozer
Collecting pysftp
/home/awulll/dapapp/.buildozer/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:315: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
/home/awulll/dapapp/.buildozer/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:120: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Using cached pysftp-0.2.8.tar.gz
Collecting paramiko>=1.7.7 (from pysftp)
  Using cached paramiko-2.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyasn1>=0.1.7 (from paramiko>=1.7.7->pysftp)
  Using cached pyasn1-0.1.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cryptography>=1.1 (from paramiko>=1.7.7->pysftp)
  Using cached cryptography-1.3.2.tar.gz
Collecting idna>=2.0 (from cryptography>=1.1->paramiko>=1.7.7->pysftp)
  Using cached idna-2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six>=1.4.1 (from cryptography>=1.1->paramiko>=1.7.7->pysftp)
  Using cached six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting setuptools>=11.3 (from cryptography>=1.1->paramiko>=1.7.7->pysftp)
  Using cached setuptools-21.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting enum34 (from cryptography>=1.1->paramiko>=1.7.7->pysftp)
  Using cached enum34-1.1.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ipaddress (from cryptography>=1.1->paramiko>=1.7.7->pysftp)
  Using cached ipaddress-1.0.16-py27-none-any.whl
Collecting cffi>=1.4.1 (from cryptography>=1.1->paramiko>=1.7.7->pysftp)
  Using cached cffi-1.6.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

        No working compiler found, or bogus compiler options
        passed to the compiler from Python's distutils module.
        See the error messages above.
        (If they are about -mno-fused-madd and you are on OS/X 10.8,
        see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/ .)

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-eC7Zv8/cffi/
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
# Command failed: pip install --target=/home/awulll/dapapp/.buildozer/applibs pysftp
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2

real    0m5.286s
user    0m3.188s
sys 0m0.357s`

I already tried check the link suggested in th log, but it doesn't help me too.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like one of the pysftp dependencies is pulling in cffi as a further dependency, which needs compilation and therefore can't be built by python-for-android without a recipe. p4a already has a cffi recipe so it will work - maybe the easiest option is to add a pysftp recipe.

You could also try getting the newest buildozer release and running `buildozer android_new debug` instead. Changes to dependency resolution might mean it work, but it also might not help - especially if buildozer itself is managing this part.

Comment: The second suggestion didn't work. I never used p4a, but I installed now and I trying to use. Hope to have good news soon =)

Comment: I tried add a recipe but I gave up. I had another idea: use paramiko (I guess pysftp uses paramiko too). I was able to build using paramiko as a require so, this solve my ftp problem for while. But as I feel this is not a answered problem yet, will keep this open.