# Python 3.5 setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 [Linux]

Tags: python, linux, pip, bots

Me and a friend are trying to setup a discord bot through DigitalOcean. However, when we run the command "`sudo -H pip3.5 install --upgrade -r requirements.txt`" or something along those lines it always ends up with the same error.
We have tried installing python, it's already up to date.

Here are the logs.

```
You may need to use sudo to install dependencies.
```

root@discord-bot:~/RadioOP# sudo -H pip3.5 install --upgrade -r requirements.txt
Collecting https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/archive/async.zip (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/archive/async.zip (442kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 450kB 2.5MB/s
Collecting youtube_dl>=2016.4.24 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Using cached youtube_dl-2016.6.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting aiohttp<0.22.0,>=0.21.0 (from discord.py==0.10.0a0->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Using cached aiohttp-0.21.6.tar.gz
Collecting websockets==3.1 (from discord.py==0.10.0a0->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Using cached websockets-3.1.tar.gz
Collecting PyNaCl==1.0.1 (from discord.py==0.10.0a0->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Using cached PyNaCl-1.0.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

```
    No working compiler found, or bogus compiler options
    passed to the compiler from Python's distutils module.
    See the error messages above.
    (If they are about -mno-fused-madd and you are on OS/X 10.8,
    see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/ .)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 243, in run_setup
    DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 273, in run
    return func()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 242, in runner
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 46, in _execfile
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "/tmp/easy_install-7oxtbavt/cffi-1.6.0/setup.py", line 111, in <module>

  File "/tmp/easy_install-7oxtbavt/cffi-1.6.0/setup.py", line 65, in ask_supports_thread

  File "/tmp/easy_install-7oxtbavt/cffi-1.6.0/setup.py", line 52, in no_working_compiler_found

SystemExit: 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1101, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 246, in run_setup
    raise
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 166, in save_modules
    saved_exc.resume()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 141, in resume
    six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 243, in run_setup
    DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 273, in run
    return func()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 242, in runner
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 46, in _execfile
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "/tmp/easy_install-7oxtbavt/cffi-1.6.0/setup.py", line 111, in <module>

  File "/tmp/easy_install-7oxtbavt/cffi-1.6.0/setup.py", line 65, in ask_supports_thread

  File "/tmp/easy_install-7oxtbavt/cffi-1.6.0/setup.py", line 52, in no_working_compiler_found

SystemExit: 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-qb7qi39t/PyNaCl/setup.py", line 259, in <module>
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5",
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 269, in __init__
    self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 313, in fetch_build_eggs
    replace_conflicting=True,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 826, in resolve
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1092, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1104, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 380, in fetch_build_egg
    return cmd.easy_install(req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 665, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 695, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 876, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1115, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1103, in run_setup
    raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))
distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with 1

----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-qb7qi39t/PyNaCl/

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Error messages belong in the question, not offsite.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know. Won't do it from now.

Comment: Excuse won't help. Please edit it into your question.

Comment: Done. The reason I didn't do it in the first place is because it looks weird. Look at it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, I fixed the problem by asking the "Discord API."

Heres how I fixed it:

> sudo apt install build-essential

and then

> sudo apt install build-essential libffi-dev python3.5-dev

and then I ran my command

Answer (score 0):

Pip tried to download PyNaCL which needs to compile a python extension module from source. For that you need to have the right development libraries installed and ofc a working compiler setup. Hence the message `no_working_compiler_found`. You can try to find a complete binary wheel for PyNaCL, install that manually and afterwards run your original install command again.

Comment: I tried adding it through putty and it gave the same error, " Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-3votjqyb/pynacl/ " when I tried to build it. I used the installation guide here: https://github.com/pyca/pynacl and downloaded it from here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyNaCl. I tried both the 32 and 64 and neither worked. Please help, here is the full errors: http://pastebin.com/rkAHjs1W