# qpython paramiko (or any other SSH python module) install

Tags: qpython, qpython3

Recently I got qpython on my android device to program python on android. I would like to connect to a SSH server from it using paramiko. However, when i try pip install paramiko from the pip console program i get the error:

```
/data/user/0/org.qpython.qpy/files/bin/qpython-android5.sh "/storage/emulated/0/qpython/scripts/pip_console.py" && exit
/qpython/scripts/pip_console.py" && exit <
Input pip commands, ie: pip install {module}
-->pip install paramiko
Downloading/unpacking paramiko
  Running setup.py egg_info for package paramiko

Downloading/unpacking cryptography>=1.1 (from paramiko)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package cryptography

    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vectors'
Downloading/unpacking pyasn1>=0.1.7 (from paramiko)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pyasn1

    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/source/.templates'
Downloading/unpacking idna>=2.1 (from cryptography>=1.1->paramiko)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package idna

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'tools'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'tests'
Downloading/unpacking asn1crypto>=0.21.0 (from cryptography>=1.1->paramiko)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package asn1crypto

Downloading/unpacking packaging (from cryptography>=1.1->paramiko)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package packaging

    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'dev-requirements.txt'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'tasks'
Downloading/unpacking six>=1.4.1 (from cryptography>=1.1->paramiko)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package six

    no previously-included directories found matching 'documentation/_build'
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): distribute in /data/data/org.qpython.qpy/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=1.1->paramiko)
Downloading/unpacking enum34 (from cryptography>=1.1->paramiko)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package enum34

Downloading/unpacking ipaddress (from cryptography>=1.1->paramiko)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package ipaddress

Downloading/unpacking cffi>=1.4.1 (from cryptography>=1.1->paramiko)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package cffi
    unable to execute arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: No such file or directory
    unable to execute arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: No such file or directory

        No working compiler found, or bogus compiler options
        passed to the compiler from Python's distutils module.
        See the error messages above.
        (If they are about -mno-fused-madd and you are on OS/X 10.8,
        see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/ .)
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    unable to execute arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: No such file or directory

unable to execute arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: No such file or directory



    No working compiler found, or bogus compiler options

    passed to the compiler from Python's distutils module.

    See the error messages above.

    (If they are about -mno-fused-madd and you are on OS/X 10.8,

    see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/ .)

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
Storing complete log in /sdcard/qpython/.pip/pip.log
-->
```

Is there anyway to get it to work or a different module that works?

Thanks in advance

P.S. qpython3 over qpython is preferable but not too much of an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Tje newest 1.4.x qpython had supported paramiko, just install the paramiko-qpython from  QPYPI.

Comment: Looks like this isn't true anymore.  qpypi has a "Featured" list but no "Libraries" list and paramiko doesn't appear.  Trying to install using pip encounters the lacking compiler issue.