# cffi package installation error on Linux

Tags: python, linux, cffi

Trying to install cffi-1.7.0 source on python 3.4.3 on my linux machine. Getting the below error.

$ python setup.py install

**cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-unused-result"
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-unused-result"**

```
No working compiler found, or bogus compiler options
passed to the compiler from Python's distutils module.
See the error messages above.
(If they are about -mno-fused-madd and you are on OS/X 10.8,
see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/ .)
```

Can any one please help me on resolving this?

Comment: You're running a version of gcc older than 4.4?

Comment: Do you have a working gcc installed on your system? On debian-based systems the package `build-essential` will be your friend.

Comment: @Patesh ,  its gcc (GCC) 4.2.1.

Comment: @Mandraenke, have  gcc (GCC) 4.2.1.  I am able to install some other packages without any issue but only 'cffi' is giving me this error.

Comment: @Patesh, Should i upgrade gcc version to 4.4? or any alternative solution is there?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved by setting below options.

setenv CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments

setenv CPPFLAGS -Qunused-arguments

Thank you all for the help!