# virtualenv pip install scrapy not working as non root user but working as root

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I am having trouble installing lxml and scrapy in my virtualenv while logged in as non root user. The installation works fine for the same environment when logged in as a root user.

The steps that I followed are as follows :

**Logged in as non root user**

```
virtualenv -p python3 test
cd test
source bin/activate
pip install lxml
```

gives:

```
Collecting lxml
  Using cached lxml-4.1.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for lxml ... error
  Complete output from command /home/intellinked/projects/test2/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-cci6wo0_/lxml/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmprzv4hx5epip-wheel- --python-tag cp37:
  Building lxml version 4.1.1.
  Building without Cython.
  Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.26
  Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /usr/lib64
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml
  copying src/lxml/doctestcompare.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml
  copying src/lxml/_elementpath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml
  copying src/lxml/sax.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml
 [truncated]
  copying src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/includes
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng/iso-schematron.rng -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/readme.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  running build_ext
  building 'lxml.etree' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/lxml
  gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DCYTHON_CLINE_IN_TRACEBACK=1 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -Isrc -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/usr/local/include/python3.7m -c src/lxml/etree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/lxml/etree.o -w
  unable to execute 'gcc': Permission denied
  Compile failed: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  creating tmp
  cc -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /tmp/xmlXPathInitk8cdu1xy.c -o tmp/xmlXPathInitk8cdu1xy.o
  unable to execute 'cc': Permission denied
  *********************************************************************************
  Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
  *********************************************************************************
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for lxml
  Running setup.py clean for lxml
Failed to build lxml
Installing collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
    Complete output from command /home/intellinked/projects/test2/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-cci6wo0_/lxml/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-cm8mq44i-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/intellinked/projects/test2/include/site/python3.7/lxml:
    Building lxml version 4.1.1.
    Building without Cython.
    Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.26
    Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /usr/lib64
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml
    copying src/lxml/doctestcompare.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/lxml
    [some more copying lines here]
    running build_ext
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/lxml
    gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DCYTHON_CLINE_IN_TRACEBACK=1 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -Isrc -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/usr/local/include/python3.7m -c src/lxml/etree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/lxml/etree.o -w
    unable to execute 'gcc': Permission denied
    Compile failed: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    cc -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /tmp/xmlXPathInit4jxbujda.c -o tmp/xmlXPathInit4jxbujda.o
    unable to execute 'cc': Permission denied
    *********************************************************************************
    Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
    *********************************************************************************
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/intellinked/projects/test2/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-cci6wo0_/lxml/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-cm8mq44i-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/intellinked/projects/test2/include/site/python3.7/lxml" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-cci6wo0_/lxml/
```

The required python dependencies were installed globally :

```
Package libxslt-devel-1.1.26-2.el6_3.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package zlib-devel-1.2.3-29.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libffi-devel-3.0.5-3.2.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package flex-2.5.35-9.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package gcc-4.4.7-18.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package redhat-rpm-config-9.0.3-51.el6.centos.noarch already installed and latest version
Package rpm-build-4.8.0-55.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package 1:make-3.81-23.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package patch-2.6-6.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package 1:pkgconfig-0.23-9.1.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package gettext-0.17-18.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package automake-1.11.1-4.el6.noarch already installed and latest version
Package bison-2.4.1-5.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libtool-2.2.6-15.5.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package autoconf-2.63-5.1.el6.noarch already installed and latest version
Package gcc-c++-4.4.7-18.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package binutils-2.20.51.0.2-5.47.el6_9.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package elfutils-0.164-2.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package cvs-1.11.23-16.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package rcs-5.7-37.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package subversion-1.6.11-15.el6_7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libffi-devel-3.0.5-3.2.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package python-devel-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package openssl-devel-1.0.1e-57.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libxml2-devel-2.7.6-21.el6_8.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

I also tried not re-compiling lxml dependencies -

```
STATIC_DEPS=true pip install lxml
```

which gives (partially truncated output):

```
Collecting lxml
  Using cached lxml-4.1.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Building lxml version 4.1.1.

    Latest version of libxml2 is 2.9.8
    Downloading libxml2 into libs/libxml2-2.9.8.tar.gz from ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/libxml2-2.9.8.tar.gz
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 2417, in retrfile
        self.ftp.cwd(file)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ftplib.py", line 631, in cwd
        return self.voidcmd(cmd)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ftplib.py", line 278, in voidcmd
        return self.voidresp()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ftplib.py", line 251, in voidresp
        resp = self.getresp()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ftplib.py", line 246, in getresp
        raise error_perm(resp)
    ftplib.error_perm: 550 Failed to change directory.

    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1539, in ftp_open
        fp, retrlen = fw.retrfile(file, type)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 2419, in retrfile
        raise URLError('ftp error: %r' % reason) from reason
    urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error ftp error: error_perm('550 Failed to change directory.',)>

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-waqe8a7a/lxml/setup.py", line 240, in <module>
        **setup_extra_options()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-waqe8a7a/lxml/setup.py", line 150, in setup_extra_options
        STATIC_CFLAGS, STATIC_BINARIES)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-waqe8a7a/lxml/setupinfo.py", line 75, in ext_modules
        multicore=OPTION_MULTICORE)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-waqe8a7a/lxml/buildlibxml.py", line 389, in build_libxml2xslt
        libxml2_dir  = unpack_tarball(download_libxml2(download_dir, libxml2_version), build_dir)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-waqe8a7a/lxml/buildlibxml.py", line 210, in download_libxml2
        version_re, filename, version=version)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-waqe8a7a/lxml/buildlibxml.py", line 291, in download_library
        urlretrieve(full_url, dest_filename)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 247, in urlretrieve
        with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
        return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
        response = self._open(req, data)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 543, in _open
        '_open', req)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1550, in ftp_open
        raise exc.with_traceback(sys.exc_info()[2])
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1539, in ftp_open
        fp, retrlen = fw.retrfile(file, type)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 2419, in retrfile
        raise URLError('ftp error: %r' % reason) from reason
    urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error ftp error: URLError("ftp error: error_perm('550 Failed to change directory.',)",)>

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-waqe8a7a/lxml
```

I face similar problems when trying to install scrapy:

```
Collecting scrapy
  Using cached Scrapy-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Twisted>=13.1.0 (from scrapy)
  Using cached Twisted-17.9.0.tar.bz2
Collecting cssselect>=0.9 (from scrapy)
  Using cached cssselect-1.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting parsel>=1.1 (from scrapy)
  Using cached parsel-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting w3lib>=1.17.0 (from scrapy)
  Using cached w3lib-1.19.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting queuelib (from scrapy)
  Using cached queuelib-1.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from scrapy)
Collecting PyDispatcher>=2.0.5 (from scrapy)
  Using cached PyDispatcher-2.0.5.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in ./lib/python3.7/site-packages (from scrapy)
Collecting pyOpenSSL (from scrapy)
  Using cached pyOpenSSL-17.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting service-identity (from scrapy)
  Using cached service_identity-17.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting zope.interface>=4.0.2 (from Twisted>=13.1.0->scrapy)
  Using cached zope.interface-4.4.3.tar.gz
Collecting constantly>=15.1 (from Twisted>=13.1.0->scrapy)
  Using cached constantly-15.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting incremental>=16.10.1 (from Twisted>=13.1.0->scrapy)
  Using cached incremental-17.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Automat>=0.3.0 (from Twisted>=13.1.0->scrapy)
  Using cached Automat-0.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting hyperlink>=17.1.1 (from Twisted>=13.1.0->scrapy)
  Using cached hyperlink-17.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cryptography>=2.1.4 (from pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
  Using cached cryptography-2.1.4.tar.gz
Collecting pyasn1-modules (from service-identity->scrapy)
  Using cached pyasn1_modules-0.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyasn1 (from service-identity->scrapy)
  Using cached pyasn1-0.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting attrs (from service-identity->scrapy)
  Using cached attrs-17.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in ./lib/python3.7/site-packages (from zope.interface>=4.0.2->Twisted>=13.1.0->scrapy)
Collecting idna>=2.1 (from cryptography>=2.1.4->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
  Using cached idna-2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting asn1crypto>=0.21.0 (from cryptography>=2.1.4->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
  Using cached asn1crypto-0.24.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cffi>=1.7 (from cryptography>=2.1.4->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
  Using cached cffi-1.11.4.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

        No working compiler found, or bogus compiler options passed to
        the compiler from Python's standard "distutils" module.  See
        the error messages above.  Likely, the problem is not related
        to CFFI but generic to the setup.py of any Python package that
        tries to compile C code.  (Hints: on OS/X 10.8, for errors about
        -mno-fused-madd see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/
        Otherwise, see https://wiki.python.org/moin/CompLangPython or
        the IRC channel #python on irc.freenode.net.)

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-kssg89y9/cffi/
```

However, if I simply instead login as root, and do the same steps within the same environment that I created as the other user, it works:

**Logged in as root**

```
cd test
source bin/activate
pip install lxml
```

gives:

```
Collecting lxml
  Downloading lxml-4.1.1.tar.gz (2.4MB)
    100% |################################| 2.4MB 587kB/s 
Building wheels for collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for lxml ... done
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/5d/14/6a/e0bbcf0b91d5add2b0caa1f704d190b36474c4d29b16f25192
Successfully built lxml
Installing collected packages: lxml
Successfully installed lxml-4.1.1
```

and pip install scrapy gives:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: Twisted, PyDispatcher, zope.interface, cryptography, cffi, pycparser
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for Twisted ... done
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/91/c7/95/0bb4d45bc4ed91375013e9b5f211ac3ebf4138d8858f84abbc
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for PyDispatcher ... done
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/86/02/a1/5857c77600a28813aaf0f66d4e4568f50c9f133277a4122411
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for zope.interface ... done
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/8b/39/98/0fcb72adfb12b2547273b1164d952f093f267e0324d58b6955
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cryptography ... error
  Complete output from command /home/intellinked/test/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-ihrybujj/cryptography/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmppn33yw48pip-wheel- --python-tag cp37:

  Installed /tmp/pip-build-ihrybujj/cryptography/.eggs/cffi-1.11.4-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg
  Searching for pycparser
  Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycparser/
  Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/8c/2d/aad7f16146f4197a11f8e91fb81df177adcc2073d36a17b1491fd09df6ed/pycparser-2.18.tar.gz#md5=72370da54358202a60130e223d488136
  Best match: pycparser 2.18
  Processing pycparser-2.18.tar.gz
  Writing /tmp/easy_install-wl_p3ddu/pycparser-2.18/setup.cfg
  Running pycparser-2.18/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-wl_p3ddu/pycparser-2.18/egg-dist-tmp-rj10qpmn
  warning: no previously-included files matching 'yacctab.*' found under directory 'tests'
  warning: no previously-included files matching 'lextab.*' found under directory 'tests'
  warning: no previously-included files matching 'yacctab.*' found under directory 'examples'
  warning: no previously-included files matching 'lextab.*' found under directory 'examples'
  zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/intellinked/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
      yield saved
    File "/home/intellinked/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
      yield
    File "/home/intellinked/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
      _execfile(setup_script, ns)
    File "/home/intellinked/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
      exec(code, globals, locals)
    File "/tmp/easy_install-wl_p3ddu/pycparser-2.18/setup.py", line 54, in <module>
      test_requirements.append("hypothesis>=1.11.4")
    File "/home/intellinked/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 129, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/home/intellinked/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 220, in run
      os.path.join(archive_root, 'EGG-INFO'), self.zip_safe()
    File "/home/intellinked/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 273, in zip_safe
      return analyze_egg(self.bdist_dir, self.stubs)
    File "/home/intellinked/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 383, in analyze_egg
      safe = scan_module(egg_dir, base, name, stubs) and safe
    File "/home/intellinked/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 422, in scan_module
      code = marshal.load(f)
  ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-build-ihrybujj/cryptography/setup.py", line 307, in <module>
      **keywords_with_side_effects(sys.argv)
    File "/home/intellinked/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 128, in setup
      _install_setup_requires(attrs)
    File "/home/intellinked/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 123, in _install_setup_requires
      dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
    [truncated lines]
    File "/home/intellinked/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 383, in analyze_egg
      safe = scan_module(egg_dir, base, name, stubs) and safe
    File "/home/intellinked/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 422, in scan_module
      code = marshal.load(f)
  ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for cryptography
  Running setup.py clean for cryptography
  Complete output from command /home/intellinked/test/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-ihrybujj/cryptography/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" clean --all:
  warning: no previously-included files matching 'yacctab.*' found under directory 'tests'
  warning: no previously-included files matching 'lextab.*' found under directory 'tests'
  warning: no previously-included files matching 'yacctab.*' found under directory 'examples'
  warning: no previously-included files matching 'lextab.*' found under directory 'examples'
  zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/intellinked/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
      yield saved
    File "/home/intellinked/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
      yield
    File "/home/intellinked/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
      _execfile(setup_script, ns)
    File "/home/intellinked/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
      exec(code, globals, locals)
    File "/tmp/easy_install-qbqn1tgi/pycparser-2.18/setup.py", line 54, in <module>
      test_requirements.append("hypothesis>=1.11.4")
    File "/home/intellinked/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 129, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/home/intellinked/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 220, in run
      os.path.join(archive_root, 'EGG-INFO'), self.zip_safe()
    File "/home/intellinked/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 273, in zip_safe
      return analyze_egg(self.bdist_dir, self.stubs)
    File "/home/intellinked/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 383, in analyze_egg
      safe = scan_module(egg_dir, base, name, stubs) and safe
    File "/home/intellinked/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 422, in scan_module
      code = marshal.load(f)
  ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-build-ihrybujj/cryptography/setup.py", line 307, in <module>
      **keywords_with_side_effects(sys.argv)
    File "/home/intellinked/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 128, in setup
      _install_setup_requires(attrs)
    [truncated lines]
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/home/intellinked/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 220, in run
      os.path.join(archive_root, 'EGG-INFO'), self.zip_safe()
    File "/home/intellinked/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 273, in zip_safe
      return analyze_egg(self.bdist_dir, self.stubs)
    File "/home/intellinked/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 383, in analyze_egg
      safe = scan_module(egg_dir, base, name, stubs) and safe
    File "/home/intellinked/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 422, in scan_module
      code = marshal.load(f)
  ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed cleaning build dir for cryptography
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cffi ... done
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/18/7f/67/c799bfa004ac33e6de1c63bf5fe927dc0ba4bb3c4b149f47e9
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pycparser ... done
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/95/14/9a/5e7b9024459d2a6600aaa64e0ba485325aff7a9ac7489db1b6
Successfully built Twisted PyDispatcher zope.interface cffi pycparser
Failed to build cryptography
Installing collected packages: six, w3lib, cssselect, pyasn1, pyasn1-modules, idna, asn1crypto, pycparser, cffi, cryptography, pyOpenSSL, attrs, service-identity, parsel, zope.interface, constantly, incremental, Automat, hyperlink, Twisted, PyDispatcher, queuelib, scrapy
  Running setup.py install for cryptography ... done
Successfully installed Automat-0.6.0 PyDispatcher-2.0.5 Twisted-17.9.0 asn1crypto-0.24.0 attrs-17.4.0 cffi-1.11.4 constantly-15.1.0 cryptography-2.1.4 cssselect-1.0.3 hyperlink-17.3.1 idna-2.6 incremental-17.5.0 parsel-1.4.0 pyOpenSSL-17.5.0 pyasn1-0.4.2 pyasn1-modules-0.2.1 pycparser-2.18 queuelib-1.4.2 scrapy-1.5.0 service-identity-17.0.0 six-1.11.0 w3lib-1.19.0 zope.interface-4.4.3
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: gcc not able to compile?  `which gcc` 
`-rwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 1026896 Sep 15 08:05 /usr/bin/gcc`

Comment: (test3) intellinked@xxxxxx.com [~/projects/test3]# which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc

Comment: sorry, I mean check the permission of gcc, it should be `755`, which allow non-root user to compile. I suspect the current setting is not `755`

Comment: That was the problem, crazy I didn't notice it! I CHMOD-ed gcc and ld to 755 and its now working as expected :)