# In yocto embedd system for source env/bin/activate : unable to execute arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc

Tags: python, yocto

run ' python -m pip install --upgrade google-assistant-sdk[samples]  ',it show below error message:

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
unable to execute 'arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc': No such file or directory
unable to execute 'arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc': No such file or directory

    No working compiler found, or bogus compiler options passed to
    the compiler from Python's standard "distutils" module.  See
    the error messages above.  Likely, the problem is not related
    to CFFI but generic to the setup.py of any Python package that
    tries to compile C code.  (Hints: on OS/X 10.8, for errors about
    -mno-fused-madd see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/
    Otherwise, see https://wiki.python.org/moin/CompLangPython or
    the IRC channel #python on irc.freenode.net.)
```

Comment: Can you edit your message to add more details on your problem?

Comment: Did you try to add it by adding `python-google-assistant-sdk` from [meta-iot-cloud](https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/meta-iot-cloud/tree/morty/recipes-google-assistant/python) to image (or python3-google-assistant-sdk). Branch is Morty but maybe it can be ported to your version.

Comment: Nayfe, it is all message.

Comment: I use the tutorial below,it is different to ur mention: https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/embed/install-sample

Comment: you can't use this, you have to do Yocto's way