# docker build is failing when snowflake dependency is included in the pip requirements

Tags: python-3.x, docker, dockerfile, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to build docker image out of my python application. But when I am adding "snowflake-connector-python" to the pip requirements.txt file the docker build is failing.

requirements.txt:-

```
boto3
pycryptodome
snowflake-connector-python
```

Dockerfile:-

```
FROM python:alpine3.6
RUN python --version

COPY . /sample-app
WORKDIR /sample-app

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --upgrade setuptools
RUN pip --version
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD [ "python", "runner.py" ]
```

CLI docker build:-

```
docker build -t sample-app:1.0 .
```

Error :-

```
Step 8/9 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 13ab5873e0b5
Collecting boto3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/92/37/bcd816851f8a04de7d2ba9df5893acc4c6680fb3ab4442895490724143fb/boto3-1.7.67-py2.py3-none-any.whl (128kB)
Collecting pycryptodome (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/96/15/a2a2aa89f57a17075579fcd296a0fcff98640776666a4371d33f7f613bb9/pycryptodome-3.6.4.tar.gz (7.1MB)
Collecting snowflake-connector-python (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/66/df/e44ec4d55fce341c9756f5f6012049b85f6a679fc3a423eefd7f66527a46/snowflake_connector_python-1.6.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (142kB)
Collecting jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 (from boto3->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b7/31/05c8d001f7f87f0f07289a5fc0fc3832e9a57f2dbd4d3b0fee70e0d51365/jmespath-0.9.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting botocore<1.11.0,>=1.10.67 (from boto3->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d6/81/59f34f9965277be8e480efea09b949e406b1afbfcf29a87c6ae6c2b52121/botocore-1.10.67-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.4MB)
Collecting s3transfer<0.2.0,>=0.1.10 (from boto3->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d7/14/2a0004d487464d120c9fb85313a75cd3d71a7506955be458eebfe19a6b1d/s3transfer-0.1.13-py2.py3-none-any.whl (59kB)
Collecting pyjwt (from snowflake-connector-python->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/93/d1/3378cc8184a6524dc92993090ee8b4c03847c567e298305d6cf86987e005/PyJWT-1.6.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyasn1<0.5.0,>=0.2.1 (from snowflake-connector-python->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d1/a1/7790cc85db38daa874f6a2e6308131b9953feb1367f2ae2d1123bb93a9f5/pyasn1-0.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (72kB)
Collecting six (from snowflake-connector-python->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/67/4b/141a581104b1f6397bfa78ac9d43d8ad29a7ca43ea90a2d863fe3056e86a/six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyOpenSSL<18.0.0,>=16.2.0 (from snowflake-connector-python->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/79/db/7c0cfe4aa8341a5fab4638952520d8db6ab85ff84505e12c00ea311c3516/pyOpenSSL-17.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (53kB)
Collecting cryptography<2.3,>=1.8.2 (from snowflake-connector-python->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ec/b2/faa78c1ab928d2b2c634c8b41ff1181f0abdd9adf9193211bd606ffa57e2/cryptography-2.2.2.tar.gz (443kB)
Collecting azure-storage<=0.36.0,>0.34.2 (from snowflake-connector-python->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/76/26/482c033f8f3a48d16cf75aad91c3e1256856719f4117fabb4696d33aa5da/azure_storage-0.36.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (190kB)
Collecting azure-common<2 (from snowflake-connector-python->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/91/66/6636001c0b6be5423f4bbaffe5febbf9eda39bd1941eb39a73504d8f6f71/azure_common-1.1.14-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ijson (from snowflake-connector-python->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7f/e9/8508c5f4987ba238a2b169e582c1f70a47272b22a2f1fb06b9318201bb9e/ijson-2.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cffi>=1.9 (from snowflake-connector-python->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e7/a7/4cd50e57cc6f436f1cc3a7e8fa700ff9b8b4d471620629074913e3735fb2/cffi-1.11.5.tar.gz (438kB)
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

        No working compiler found, or bogus compiler options passed to
        the compiler from Python's standard "distutils" module.  See
        the error messages above.  Likely, the problem is not related
        to CFFI but generic to the setup.py of any Python package that
        tries to compile C code.  (Hints: on OS/X 10.8, for errors about
        -mno-fused-madd see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/
        Otherwise, see https://wiki.python.org/moin/CompLangPython or
        the IRC channel #python on irc.freenode.net.)

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-7dudc372/cffi/
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

What could be the issue ? Am I missing something here ?

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/python-connector-install.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

alpine linux is very tiny and they had to remove everything so you will have to install it yourself. Some pip packages require to be compiled/build on your machine but alpine is missing these depedencies, so install them, then do your pip install and then remove them cause they are not required anymore and you will reduce the image size.

The snowflake [docs](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/python-connector-install.html) also say you have to install `libffi-dev` and `openssl-dev`

```
FROM python:alpine3.6

COPY . /sample-app
WORKDIR /sample-app

RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev libc-dev linux-headers libxslt-dev libxml2-dev \
&& apk add libffi-dev openssl-dev \
&& pip install --upgrade pip setuptools \
&& pip install -r requirements.txt \
&& apk del build-deps

CMD [ "python", "runner.py" ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the compilation libraries/package to your alpine image, add below `RUN` statement in your Dockerfile above/before `pip install` -

```
WORKDIR /sample-app
RUN apk add --no-cache build-base libffi-dev openssl-dev ncurses-dev
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

This basically installs gcc, g++ & make to compile packages, other packages are required too in your case. I guess they are removed or not shipped with original `python:alpine3.6` image.

Answer (score 0):

I found that using [virtual env](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html#python-package-venv) on top of linux helps when building a python deployment package for AWS lambda, not sure if that is helpful here.

I needed to `yum -y install gcc libffi-devel openssl-devel` like Mazel Tov suggested, to get remaining dependencies not included with pip.