# How do I sucessfully install python-telegram-bot into Termux?

Tags: python, linux, pip, termux

I have a problem. I made a simple web scraping telegram bot and I want it to run on my old phone. However, I am not able to install python-telegram-bot via pip. I get this weird error message. Does anyone know how do I tackle this issue? Thank you

```
> $ pip install python-telegram-bot Collecting python-telegram-bot  
> Using cached
> https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/84/6c/47932a4041ee76650ad1f45a80e1422077e1e99c08a4d7a61cfbe5393d41/python_telegram_bot-11.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
> Collecting future>=0.16.0 (from python-telegram-bot)   Using cached
> https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/90/52/e20466b85000a181e1e144fd8305caf2cf475e2f9674e797b222f8105f5f/future-0.17.1.tar.gz
> Collecting certifi (from python-telegram-bot)   Using cached
> https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/56/9d/1d02dd80bc4cd955f98980f28c5ee2200e1209292d5f9e9cc8d030d18655/certifi-2018.10.15-py2.py3-none-any.whl
> Collecting cryptography (from python-telegram-bot)   Using cached
> https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f3/39/d3904df7c56f8654691c4ae1bdb270c1c9220d6da79bd3b1fbad91afd0e1/cryptography-2.4.2.tar.gz
> Installing build dependencies ... error   Complete output from command
> /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/python -m pip install
> --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-cvyz6a4p
> --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools>=18.5 wheel "cffi>=1.7,!=1.11.3;
> python_implementation != 'PyPy'":   Collecting setuptools>=18.5
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e7/16/da8cb8046149d50940c6110310983abb359bbb8cbc3539e6bef95c29428a/setuptools-40.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
> Collecting wheel
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ff/47/1dfa4795e24fd6f93d5d58602dd716c3f101cfd5a77cd9acbe519b44a0a9/wheel-0.32.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
> Collecting cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.7
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e7/a7/4cd50e57cc6f436f1cc3a7e8fa700ff9b8b4d471620629074913e3735fb2/cffi-1.11.5.tar.gz
>       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
> 
>           No working compiler found, or bogus compiler options passed to
>           the compiler from Python's standard "distutils" module.  See
>           the error messages above.  Likely, the problem is not related
>           to CFFI but generic to the setup.py of any Python package that
>           tries to compile C code.  (Hints: on OS/X 10.8, for errors about
>           -mno-fused-madd see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/
>           Otherwise, see https://wiki.python.org/moin/CompLangPython or
>           the IRC channel #python on irc.freenode.net.)
> 
>       ----------------------------------------   Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
> /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-kqmk4olx/cffi/
> 
>   ---------------------------------------- Command
> "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/python -m pip install
> --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-build-env-cvyz6a4p
> --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools>=18.5 wheel "cffi>=1.7,!=1.11.3;
> python_implementation != 'PyPy'"" failed with error code 1 in None $
```

Comment: What "weird error message"?

Comment: It is on the screenshot that "error" links to.

Comment: Please dont include links to errors, links can expire. Your link also cuts off the text so we can't read the traceback properly

Comment: It's right there in the error message: you don't have a C compiler (like, e.g., gcc) installed

Answer (score 0):

You have to have development toolchain (a compiler and all that) for Termux. By default you can [install clang](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Instructions_for_installing_python_packages):

```
 pkg install clang python-dev
```

You can also try gcc, see

https://android.stackexchange.com/a/186223

and

https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Package_Management#Community_repositories