# Can't install python module with Dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, gcc

I am unable to install Flask-User from my requirements file as when it comes to that module I get the error:

```
Collecting bcrypt>=2.0 (from flask-user->-r requirements.txt (line 8))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ce/3a/3d540b9f5ee8d92ce757eebacf167b9deedb8e30aedec69a2a072b2399bb/bcrypt-3.1.6.tar.gz (42kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'
  Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-vtowffrv/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel "cffi>=1.1; python_implementation != 'PyPy'":
  Collecting setuptools
    Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/82/9c/e812a9838feaf76cd9a960ca4ced3be7f2db31e473677a621d006e128db2/setuptools-40.7.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (574kB)
  Collecting wheel
    Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ff/47/1dfa4795e24fd6f93d5d58602dd716c3f101cfd5a77cd9acbe519b44a0a9/wheel-0.32.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting cffi>=1.1
    Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e7/a7/4cd50e57cc6f436f1cc3a7e8fa700ff9b8b4d471620629074913e3735fb2/cffi-1.11.5.tar.gz (438kB)
      Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

          No working compiler found, or bogus compiler options passed to
          the compiler from Python's standard "distutils" module.  See
          the error messages above.  Likely, the problem is not related
          to CFFI but generic to the setup.py of any Python package that
          tries to compile C code.  (Hints: on OS/X 10.8, for errors about
          -mno-fused-madd see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/
          Otherwise, see https://wiki.python.org/moin/CompLangPython or
          the IRC channel #python on irc.freenode.net.)

      ----------------------------------------
  Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-wt1ra3xd/cffi/

  ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-vtowffrv/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel "cffi>=1.1; python_implementation != 'PyPy'"" failed with error code 1 in None
ERROR: Service 'frontend' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I have tried to upgrade pip, and install setuptools to no avail.

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app
COPY app.py /app
COPY templates /app/templates
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

requirements.txt:

```
Flask
requests
jsonify
pymongo
request
wtforms
flask-mongoengine
flask-user
```

Edit:

Appears gcc is not included in the alpine base image.
I resolved this issue by using `FROM python:3.6-slim` instead.

Comment: can you post requirements.txt also there is no problem with dockerfile

Comment: Seems like you're missing the gcc

Comment: @Gaurav Done. I've come across a few people getting this problem, but none of the solutions worked for me.

Comment: you need to update python dev tools to solve this issue, give me some moments

Comment: is alpine image necessary?

Comment: @Gaurav not necessarily, was just trying to speed up my times and had no issues prior to this module. Can use `FROM python:3.6-slim` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears gcc is not included in the alpine base image. I resolved this issue by using `FROM python:3.6-slim` instead.