# Docker build behaving differently on different machines

Tags: macos, docker, raspberry-pi, dockerfile

I have created a Docker image on my Mac. It builds just fine there. When I try to build the same Dockerfile on my Raspberry Pi, it doesn't build anymore.

A simplified version of the Dockerfile looks like this (this still creates the same error):

```
FROM python:3.6-slim

RUN pip install --upgrade pip \    
  && pip install cffi==1.11.5
```

And the error looks like:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB 
Step 1/2 : FROM python:3.6-slim  ---> 61de9ac6fc45  
Step 2/2 : RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install cffi==1.11.5  ---> Running in 6f3799252081   
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (19.0.2)   
Collecting cffi==1.11.5     
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e7/a7/4cd50e57cc6f436f1cc3a7e8fa700ff9b8b4d471620629074913e3735fb2/cffi-1.11.5.tar.gz (438kB)  
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

        No working compiler found, or bogus compiler options passed to
        the compiler from Python's standard "distutils" module.  See
        the error messages above.  Likely, the problem is not related
        to CFFI but generic to the setup.py of any Python package that
        tries to compile C code.  (Hints: on OS/X 10.8, for errors about
        -mno-fused-madd see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/
        Otherwise, see https://wiki.python.org/moin/CompLangPython or
        the IRC channel #python on irc.freenode.net.)

    ---------------------------------------- 
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-w0vf1obt/cffi/ The command '/bin/sh -c pip install --upgrade pip    && pip install cffi==1.11.5' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

The version of Docker on my Mac is 18.09.1, build 4c52b90, and on my Raspberry Pi 18.09.0, build 4d60db4.

I ran `docker system prune -a` on both machines, and tried different versions of the python base image.

To me this makes no sense, and it defies the entire purpose of using Docker in the first place.

Can anyone explain to me how it is possible that Docker behaves differently like this on different machines? Is it caused by different versions of Docker ? Is it maybe because the `docker system prune -a` command doesn't clean up everything properly? Or is it because docker behaves differently on Mac VS Raspberry Pi?

Comment: This may be related to architecture. Most modern computers are AMD64, but the Raspberry Pi is ARM. Different architectures need different images, and it's possible something's wrong with the ARM Python image.

Comment: You are right that when I run `docker inspect python:3.6-slim` on both machines, the only difference is the architecture of the images (i.e. AMD vs ARM). Does this mean I can't ship images from a normal computer to my Raspberry Pi (pushing the image to docker hub also doesn't seem to work)?

Comment: Have you found the answer to this?