# Building a docker image for a flask app fails in pip

Tags: python, docker, pip

```
from alpine:latest
RUN apk add --no-cache python3-dev \
    && pip3 install --upgrade pip

WORKDIR /backend
COPY . /backend

RUN pip --no-cache-dir install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ['python3']
CMD ['app.py']
```

I have a simple Dockerfile that looks like above.

When I do `docker build -t backend:latest .`, it gives me

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3.7 /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-wr55ljb4/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel 'cffi>=1.1; python_implementation != '"'"'PyPy'"'"'' Check the logs for full command output.
The command '/bin/sh -c pip --no-cache-dir install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Seems like my pip is not working properly. Any thoughts?

**error log**

```
Step 5/8 : RUN pip --no-cache-dir install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 22ceccf0fd82
Collecting asn1crypto==0.24.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ea/cd/35485615f45f30a510576f1a56d1e0a7ad7bd8ab5ed7cdc600ef7cd06222/asn1crypto-0.24.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (101kB)
Collecting bcrypt==3.1.7 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fa/aa/025a3ab62469b5167bc397837c9ffc486c42a97ef12ceaa6699d8f5a5416/bcrypt-3.1.7.tar.gz (42kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-kjhqh8sc/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel 'cffi>=1.1; python_implementation != '"'"'PyPy'"'"''
       cwd: None
  Complete output (169 lines):
  Collecting setuptools>=40.8.0
    Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/75/b3/0a106dfaf7f48aef638da80b32608617cc8de4b24a22c8cd3759c32e5d30/setuptools-41.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (576kB)
  Collecting wheel
    Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bb/10/44230dd6bf3563b8f227dbf344c908d412ad2ff48066476672f3a72e174e/wheel-0.33.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting cffi>=1.1
    Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/93/1a/ab8c62b5838722f29f3daffcc8d4bd61844aa9b5f437341cc890ceee483b/cffi-1.12.3.tar.gz (456kB)
  Collecting pycparser (from cffi>=1.1)
    Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/68/9e/49196946aee219aead1290e00d1e7fdeab8567783e83e1b9ab5585e6206a/pycparser-2.19.tar.gz (158kB)
  Building wheels for collected packages: cffi, pycparser
    Building wheel for cffi (setup.py): started
    Building wheel for cffi (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-68ehjxmi/cffi/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-68ehjxmi/cffi/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-hdxzm2ih --python-tag cp36
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-68ehjxmi/cffi/
    Complete output (68 lines):
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    Package 'libffi', required by 'virtual:world', not found
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    Package 'libffi', required by 'virtual:world', not found
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    Package 'libffi', required by 'virtual:world', not found
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    Package 'libffi', required by 'virtual:world', not found
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    Package 'libffi', required by 'virtual:world', not found
    unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
    unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory

        No working compiler found, or bogus compiler options passed to
        the compiler from Python's standard "distutils" module.  See
        the error messages above.  Likely, the problem is not related
        to CFFI but generic to the setup.py of any Python package that
        tries to compile C code.  (Hints: on OS/X 10.8, for errors about
        -mno-fused-madd see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/
        Otherwise, see https://wiki.python.org/moin/CompLangPython or
        the IRC channel #python on irc.freenode.net.)

        Trying to continue anyway.  If you are trying to install CFFI from
        a build done in a different context, you can ignore this warning.

    running bdist_wheel
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
    copying cffi/cparser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
    copying cffi/cffi_opcode.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
    copying cffi/pkgconfig.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
    copying cffi/lock.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
    copying cffi/vengine_cpy.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
    copying cffi/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
    copying cffi/vengine_gen.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
    copying cffi/verifier.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
    copying cffi/setuptools_ext.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
    copying cffi/commontypes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
    copying cffi/recompiler.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
    copying cffi/model.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
    copying cffi/backend_ctypes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
    copying cffi/api.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
    copying cffi/error.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
    copying cffi/ffiplatform.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
    copying cffi/_cffi_include.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
    copying cffi/parse_c_type.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
    copying cffi/_embedding.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
    copying cffi/_cffi_errors.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
    running build_ext
    building '_cffi_backend' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/c
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -DTHREAD_STACK_SIZE=0x100000 -fPIC -I/usr/include/ffi -I/usr/include/libffi -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c c/_cffi_backend.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/c/_cffi_backend.o
    unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for cffi
    Running setup.py clean for cffi
    Building wheel for pycparser (setup.py): started
    Building wheel for pycparser (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
    Created wheel for pycparser: filename=pycparser-2.19-py2.py3-none-any.whl size=111031 sha256=7214a0d655238f2c9991c7a92ece87d949521239504b9dcc5b2e8ac2f438679a
    Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/f2/9a/90/de94f8556265ddc9d9c8b271b0f63e57b26fb1d67a45564511
  Successfully built pycparser
  Failed to build cffi
  Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel, pycparser, cffi
    Running setup.py install for cffi: started
      Running setup.py install for cffi: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-68ehjxmi/cffi/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-68ehjxmi/cffi/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-oq4j1nik/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-kjhqh8sc/overlay --compile
           cwd: /tmp/pip-install-68ehjxmi/cffi/
      Complete output (68 lines):
      Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
      Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
      to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
      Package 'libffi', required by 'virtual:world', not found
      Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
      Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
      to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
      Package 'libffi', required by 'virtual:world', not found
      Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
      Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
      to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
      Package 'libffi', required by 'virtual:world', not found
      Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
      Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
      to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
      Package 'libffi', required by 'virtual:world', not found
      Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
      Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
      to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
      Package 'libffi', required by 'virtual:world', not found
      unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
      unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory

          No working compiler found, or bogus compiler options passed to
          the compiler from Python's standard "distutils" module.  See
          the error messages above.  Likely, the problem is not related
          to CFFI but generic to the setup.py of any Python package that
          tries to compile C code.  (Hints: on OS/X 10.8, for errors about
          -mno-fused-madd see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/
          Otherwise, see https://wiki.python.org/moin/CompLangPython or
          the IRC channel #python on irc.freenode.net.)

          Trying to continue anyway.  If you are trying to install CFFI from
          a build done in a different context, you can ignore this warning.

      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
      copying cffi/cparser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
      copying cffi/cffi_opcode.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
      copying cffi/pkgconfig.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
      copying cffi/lock.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
      copying cffi/vengine_cpy.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
      copying cffi/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
      copying cffi/vengine_gen.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
      copying cffi/verifier.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
      copying cffi/setuptools_ext.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
      copying cffi/commontypes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
      copying cffi/recompiler.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
      copying cffi/model.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
      copying cffi/backend_ctypes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
      copying cffi/api.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
      copying cffi/error.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
      copying cffi/ffiplatform.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
      copying cffi/_cffi_include.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
      copying cffi/parse_c_type.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
      copying cffi/_embedding.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
      copying cffi/_cffi_errors.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/cffi
      running build_ext
      building '_cffi_backend' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/c
      gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -DTHREAD_STACK_SIZE=0x100000 -fPIC -I/usr/include/ffi -I/usr/include/libffi -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c c/_cffi_backend.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/c/_cffi_backend.o
      unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
      error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-68ehjxmi/cffi/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-68ehjxmi/cffi/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-oq4j1nik/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-kjhqh8sc/overlay --compile Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-kjhqh8sc/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel 'cffi>=1.1; python_implementation != '"'"'PyPy'"'"'' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 19):

I struggled with that for a moment as well. I ended up creating my container with

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

RUN apk update && apk add gcc libc-dev make git libffi-dev openssl-dev python3-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev
```

Anyway, if you want to use `alpine:latest` you probably just need some of the os dependencies I listed above.

Comment: saved me but ignoring the last two pkgs as well as make and git.