# Linux Alpine not reading special characters like $# from password

Tags: linux

Linux not reading special characters like $# from password

```
Password =  Special5$#

When i enter password its going as Special50  ( instead $# I'm seeing 0)
```

Command

1 ) Here I ran this export USER_PASSWORD='Special5$#'

Pip command to install package , on running getting an error ValueError

```
pip3 install --index-url "https://A600211:$USER_PASSWORD@artifactory.code.xxx.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-virtual/simple" stunner
```

```
Error 

ValueError: Port could not be cast to integer value as 'Special5'
```

2nd Way - On trying directly by giving password in pip3 install  ( note that there are no Double quotes in below command

```
pip3 install --index-url https://A6002043:'Special5$#'@artifactory.code.xxx.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-virtual/simple stunner

Error 

ValueError: Port could not be cast to integer value as 'Special5$'   ( here I see # is missing)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are building a URL but you are neglecting URL encoding.

Instead of

```
USER_PASSWORD='Special5$#'
```

use

```
USER_PASSWORD='Special5%24%23'
```

Comment: ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-ucxxjdpy/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://A6002043:Special5%24%23@artifactory.code.xxxxxx.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-virtual/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel 'cffi>=1.1; python_implementation != '"'"'PyPy'"'"''

Comment: Sounds like `pip3` no longer has a problem with the URL, so you're now progressing and running into [other unrelated issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57520642/building-a-docker-image-for-a-flask-app-fails-in-pip).

Answer (score 1):

use a single quote to force the shell interpreter to read the string as-is instead of expanding the string as a variable.

```
Password = 'Special5$#'
```

Comment: ValueError: Port could not be cast to integer value as 'Special5'      Im seeing this error

Comment: That seems like an unrelated issue. Are you sure pip3 supports providing passwords in that manner?

Comment: Note that the information about this being pip was not provided when I answered.