# packages are not installing using Dockerfile

Tags: python, docker

I am new in python and using python:3.7.13-alpine3.15  docker image, while downloading the packages, I am seeing the below error. Can someone suggest something?

I have already tried changing the docker image to non-alpine image. but that did not help.

**Error:**

---

executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps g++ libxml2 libxml2-dev alpine-sdk py3-cffi libffi-dev libxslt-dev python3-dev]: exit code: 2

**Docker file:**

```
FROM python:3.7.13-alpine3.15
RUN apk update
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps g++ libxml2 libxml2-dev alpine-sdk py3-cffi libffi-dev libxslt-dev python3-dev
RUN pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
RUN pip --version
RUN python --version
WORKDIR ./
RUN apk add --update alpine-sdk py3-cffi libffi-dev
RUN python -m venv /opt/venv
# Enable venv
ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -Ur "requirements.txt"
```

**Requirements.txt:**
following packages are being installed

```
    beautifulsoup4==4.9.3
    certifi==2020.12.5
    chardet==4.0.0
    idna==2.10
    lxml==4.6.2
    nuclio-sdk==0.2.0
    pycparser==2.20
    PyJWT==2.0.1
    pymongo==3.11.2
    pysolr==3.9.0
    py7zr==0.16.1
    python-memcached==1.59
    PyYAML==5.4
    requests==2.25.1
    six==1.15.0
    urllib3==1.26.2
    zeep==4.1.0
    requests-kerberos==0.14.0
```

Comment: What is your Dockerfile, what is your requirement file?

Comment: @CutePoison, Please check the edited  question.

Answer (score 0):

If I `pip install bcj-cffi` in a shell using that image, the error message is much more descriptive and points to the source of the problem:

```
$ docker run -it --rm python:3.7.13-alpine3.15 sh
/ # pip install bcj-cffi
Collecting bcj-cffi
  Downloading bcj-cffi-0.5.1.tar.gz (35 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error


        × Running setup.py install for cffi did not run successfully.
        │ exit code: 1
        ╰─> [48 lines of output]
            unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
            unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory

                No working compiler found, or bogus compiler options passed to
                the compiler from Python's standard "distutils" module.  See
                the error messages above.  Likely, the problem is not related
                to CFFI but generic to the setup.py of any Python package that
                tries to compile C code.  (Hints: on OS/X 10.8, for errors about
                -mno-fused-madd see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/
                Otherwise, see https://wiki.python.org/moin/CompLangPython or
                the IRC channel #python on irc.libera.chat.)
  ...
```

The problem here is that that the `bcj-cffi` module has a number of non-Python depdendencies. In order to successfully install `bcf-cffi`, I had to first install:

```
apk add --update alpine-sdk py3-cffi libffi-dev
```

After this, I was able to sucessfully `pip install bcj-cffi`.

(The `alpine-sdk` package is effectively shorthand for "a reasonable C build environment".)

Comment: error: subprocess-exited-with-error
01:34:06    
01:34:06    × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
01:34:06    │ exit code: 1
01:34:06    ╰─> [25 lines of output]
01:34:06        /bin/sh: krb5-config: not found
01:34:06        In distributed package, building from C files...
01:34:06        Using krb5-config at 'krb5-config'
01:34:06        Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: I can't reproduce that behavior. You can see a complete record of my successful install [here](https://asciinema.org/a/ztIgetePcvOwtIr8cmV4ZcsbK). If you're executing the same sequence of steps and getting different results, I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for the support. I am now using docker file to check it locally and seeing above issue.