# Build multi-arch docker image

Tags: docker, build, docker-image, multiarch

I try to build an ansible image for amd64 and arm64 using `docker buildx` but my build always fails, it's like the builder can't support another arch than the one running on the current hardware I am running debian and I installed `qemu-user-static` and `binfmt-support` so `docker buildx` ls gives the following result

```
NAME/NODE           DRIVER/ENDPOINT             STATUS  PLATFORMS
hopeful_wilson *    docker-container                    
  hopeful_wilson0   unix:///var/run/docker.sock running linux/amd64, linux/amd64/v2, linux/amd64/v3, linux/arm64, linux/riscv64, linux/ppc64le, linux/s390x, linux/386, linux/mips64le, linux/mips64, linux/arm/v7, linux/arm/v6
inspiring_lamarr    docker-container                    
  inspiring_lamarr0 unix:///var/run/docker.sock running linux/amd64, linux/amd64/v2, linux/amd64/v3, linux/arm64, linux/riscv64, linux/ppc64le, linux/s390x, linux/386, linux/mips64le, linux/mips64, linux/arm/v7, linux/arm/v6
default             docker                              
  default           default                     running linux/amd64, linux/386, linux/arm64, linux/riscv64, linux/ppc64le, linux/s390x, linux/arm/v7, linux/arm/v6
```

and my dockerfile

```
FROM python:alpine3.15

ADD . /tmp
WORKDIR /tmp 

RUN adduser -D -s /bin/sh -h /home/ansible ansible ansible
RUN apk update && apk add openssh-client bash
RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
# RUN python3 -m pip install ansible
RUN sed -i "s@/bin/sh@/bin/bash@g" /etc/passwd

WORKDIR /

USER ansible
```

to build I run

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 -t ansible-multi-arch .
```

And here the result of my build

```
 WARNING: No output specified for docker-container driver. Build result will only remain in the build cache. To push result image into registry use --push or to load image into docker use --load
[+] Building 121.4s (24/25)                                                                                                                                                        
 => [internal] booting buildkit                                                                                                                                               5.8s
 => => pulling image moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1                                                                                                                            1.9s
 => => creating container buildx_buildkit_competent_bohr0                                                                                                                     3.9s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                          0.8s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 419B                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                             0.9s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [linux/amd64 internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:alpine3.15                                                                                              3.0s
 => [linux/arm64 internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:alpine3.15                                                                                              3.2s
 => [auth] library/python:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [linux/arm64  1/10] FROM docker.io/library/python:alpine3.15@sha256:74d722200c8cd876dcbd5cfb1d093c916e85d4318f051c2f3cfe5067c27cfbd5                                     12.9s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/python:alpine3.15@sha256:74d722200c8cd876dcbd5cfb1d093c916e85d4318f051c2f3cfe5067c27cfbd5                                                    0.3s
 => => sha256:7025a0ca8e87cb11983c19a8a09007c64a9ebe5d2f9efe96b36658d2221721b7 231B / 231B                                                                                    0.5s
 => => sha256:a1b0595ea6d26aa03a510d790d1fde94888af6ca5914982b6c9b6fd03c7a620c 3.04MB / 3.04MB                                                                                1.5s
 => => sha256:938e9f93fe23985a1f4d1d090e4ced82c31b2fabd4922b7761e42cfe7b56b9d7 12.67MB / 12.67MB                                                                              3.3s
 => => sha256:5e18021c0d0bf0a6f79a44bbbd33f12adeb2ef1358b140d8e7ef36e20c1e63b3 682.39kB / 682.39kB                                                                            0.7s
 => => sha256:47517142f6ba87eca6b7bdca1e0df160b74671c81e4b9605dad38c1862a43be3 2.72MB / 2.72MB                                                                                1.2s
 => => extracting sha256:47517142f6ba87eca6b7bdca1e0df160b74671c81e4b9605dad38c1862a43be3                                                                                     0.3s
 => => extracting sha256:5e18021c0d0bf0a6f79a44bbbd33f12adeb2ef1358b140d8e7ef36e20c1e63b3                                                                                     0.5s
 => => extracting sha256:938e9f93fe23985a1f4d1d090e4ced82c31b2fabd4922b7761e42cfe7b56b9d7                                                                                     1.6s
 => => extracting sha256:7025a0ca8e87cb11983c19a8a09007c64a9ebe5d2f9efe96b36658d2221721b7                                                                                     1.7s
 => => extracting sha256:a1b0595ea6d26aa03a510d790d1fde94888af6ca5914982b6c9b6fd03c7a620c                                                                                     1.6s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                             1.4s
 => => transferring context: 49.12kB                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [linux/amd64  1/10] FROM docker.io/library/python:alpine3.15@sha256:74d722200c8cd876dcbd5cfb1d093c916e85d4318f051c2f3cfe5067c27cfbd5                                      9.0s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/python:alpine3.15@sha256:74d722200c8cd876dcbd5cfb1d093c916e85d4318f051c2f3cfe5067c27cfbd5                                                    0.3s
 => => sha256:4211f440f0679002fb62db619c32ebb8894e25c77a19249fdf742fd4dbfb6555 3.04MB / 3.04MB                                                                                0.7s
 => => sha256:e8792c1c2edc87ab51a97c35dd511344734a625d1e67e3fd27dcfaa37ebe8eaf 231B / 231B                                                                                    0.3s
 => => sha256:abed0206f3914209d0e7a549b92f3b0c85b421285ab998e63ea64d093f71289f 681.67kB / 681.67kB                                                                            1.3s
 => => sha256:9621f1afde84053b2f9b6ff34fc7f7460712247c01cbab483c5fa7132cf782ca 2.82MB / 2.82MB                                                                                1.1s
 => => sha256:0b0ae0fe5b972748ea6475feec4cd2238797fd89b8870a9f4a572f29488e5f88 12.58MB / 12.58MB                                                                              2.8s
 => => extracting sha256:9621f1afde84053b2f9b6ff34fc7f7460712247c01cbab483c5fa7132cf782ca                                                                                     0.4s
 => => extracting sha256:abed0206f3914209d0e7a549b92f3b0c85b421285ab998e63ea64d093f71289f                                                                                     0.7s
 => => extracting sha256:0b0ae0fe5b972748ea6475feec4cd2238797fd89b8870a9f4a572f29488e5f88                                                                                     0.5s
 => => extracting sha256:e8792c1c2edc87ab51a97c35dd511344734a625d1e67e3fd27dcfaa37ebe8eaf                                                                                     0.3s
 => => extracting sha256:4211f440f0679002fb62db619c32ebb8894e25c77a19249fdf742fd4dbfb6555                                                                                     1.6s
 => [linux/amd64  2/10] ADD . /tmp                                                                                                                                            7.0s
 => [linux/arm64  2/10] ADD . /tmp                                                                                                                                            3.5s
 => [linux/arm64  3/10] WORKDIR /tmp                                                                                                                                          1.9s
 => [linux/amd64  3/10] WORKDIR /tmp                                                                                                                                          1.9s
 => [linux/arm64  4/10] RUN adduser -D -s /bin/sh -h /home/ansible ansible ansible                                                                                            1.6s
 => [linux/amd64  4/10] RUN adduser -D -s /bin/sh -h /home/ansible ansible ansible                                                                                            1.6s
 => [linux/arm64  5/10] RUN apk update && apk add openssh-client bash                                                                                                         4.3s
 => [linux/amd64  5/10] RUN apk update && apk add openssh-client bash                                                                                                         2.6s
 => [linux/amd64  6/10] RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*                                                                                                                           0.5s
 => [linux/amd64  7/10] RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip                                                                                                              5.9s
 => [linux/arm64  6/10] RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*                                                                                                                           1.2s
 => [linux/arm64  7/10] RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip                                                                                                             23.5s
 => [linux/amd64  8/10] RUN python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt                                                                                                       43.1s 
 => ERROR [linux/arm64  8/10] RUN python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt                                                                                                 61.9s 
 => [linux/amd64  9/10] RUN sed -i "s@/bin/sh@/bin/bash@g" /etc/passwd                                                                                                        1.4s
------
 > [linux/arm64  8/10] RUN python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt:
#0 3.679 Collecting ansible==6.3.0
#0 3.820   Downloading ansible-6.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (41.0 MB)
#0 8.925      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 41.0/41.0 MB 5.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#0 10.81 Collecting ansible-core==2.13.3
#0 10.84   Downloading ansible_core-2.13.3-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
#0 11.12      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.1/2.1 MB 7.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#0 12.29 Collecting cffi==1.15.1
#0 12.32   Downloading cffi-1.15.1.tar.gz (508 kB)
#0 12.77      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 508.5/508.5 kB 1.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#0 13.15   Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
#0 17.85   Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
#0 18.91 Collecting cryptography==37.0.4
#0 18.95   Downloading cryptography-37.0.4-cp36-abi3-musllinux_1_1_aarch64.whl (4.1 MB)
#0 19.47      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 4.1/4.1 MB 8.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#0 20.18 Collecting Jinja2==3.1.2
#0 20.22   Downloading Jinja2-3.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
#0 20.68      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 133.1/133.1 kB 291.5 kB/s eta 0:00:00
#0 21.19 Collecting MarkupSafe==2.1.1
#0 21.22   Downloading MarkupSafe-2.1.1-cp310-cp310-musllinux_1_1_aarch64.whl (30 kB)
#0 22.11 Collecting packaging==21.3
#0 22.15   Downloading packaging-21.3-py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
#0 22.48      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 40.8/40.8 kB 96.3 kB/s eta 0:00:00
#0 23.14 Collecting pycparser==2.21
#0 23.17   Downloading pycparser-2.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (118 kB)
#0 23.25      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 118.7/118.7 kB 2.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#0 23.55 Collecting pyparsing==3.0.9
#0 23.58   Downloading pyparsing-3.0.9-py3-none-any.whl (98 kB)
#0 23.66      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 98.3/98.3 kB 2.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#0 23.94 Collecting PyYAML==6.0
#0 23.97   Downloading PyYAML-6.0.tar.gz (124 kB)
#0 24.25      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 125.0/125.0 kB 479.8 kB/s eta 0:00:00
#0 25.03   Installing build dependencies: started
#0 39.09   Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
#0 39.09   Getting requirements to build wheel: started
#0 46.71   Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
#0 46.73   Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
#0 48.48   Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
#0 48.66 Collecting resolvelib==0.8.1
#0 48.70   Downloading resolvelib-0.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
#0 49.30 Building wheels for collected packages: cffi, PyYAML
#0 49.30   Building wheel for cffi (setup.py): started
#0 50.82   Building wheel for cffi (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
#0 50.86   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#0 50.86   
#0 50.86   × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
#0 50.86   │ exit code: 1
#0 50.86   ╰─> [47 lines of output]
#0 50.86       
#0 50.86           No working compiler found, or bogus compiler options passed to
#0 50.86           the compiler from Python's standard "distutils" module.  See
#0 50.86           the error messages above.  Likely, the problem is not related
#0 50.86           to CFFI but generic to the setup.py of any Python package that
#0 50.86           tries to compile C code.  (Hints: on OS/X 10.8, for errors about
#0 50.86           -mno-fused-madd see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/
#0 50.86           Otherwise, see https://wiki.python.org/moin/CompLangPython or
#0 50.86           the IRC channel #python on irc.libera.chat.)
#0 50.86       
#0 50.86           Trying to continue anyway.  If you are trying to install CFFI from
#0 50.86           a build done in a different context, you can ignore this warning.
#0 50.86       
#0 50.86       /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/config/setupcfg.py:463: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
#0 50.86         warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)
#0 50.86       running bdist_wheel
#0 50.86       running build
#0 50.86       running build_py
#0 50.86       creating build
#0 50.86       creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310
#0 50.86       creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 50.86       copying cffi/setuptools_ext.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 50.86       copying cffi/error.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 50.86       copying cffi/vengine_cpy.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 50.86       copying cffi/pkgconfig.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 50.86       copying cffi/commontypes.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 50.86       copying cffi/backend_ctypes.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 50.86       copying cffi/lock.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 50.86       copying cffi/vengine_gen.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 50.86       copying cffi/api.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 50.86       copying cffi/verifier.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 50.86       copying cffi/model.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 50.86       copying cffi/cparser.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 50.86       copying cffi/cffi_opcode.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 50.86       copying cffi/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 50.86       copying cffi/recompiler.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 50.86       copying cffi/ffiplatform.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 50.86       copying cffi/_cffi_include.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 50.86       copying cffi/parse_c_type.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 50.86       copying cffi/_embedding.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 50.86       copying cffi/_cffi_errors.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 50.86       running build_ext
#0 50.86       building '_cffi_backend' extension
#0 50.86       creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310
#0 50.86       creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/c
#0 50.86       gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -DTHREAD_STACK_SIZE=0x100000 -fPIC -DFFI_BUILDING=1 -I/usr/include/ffi -I/usr/include/libffi -I/usr/local/include/python3.10 -c c/_cffi_backend.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/c/_cffi_backend.o
#0 50.86       error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory
#0 50.86       [end of output]
#0 50.86   
#0 50.86   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
#0 50.87   ERROR: Failed building wheel for cffi
#0 50.87   Running setup.py clean for cffi
#0 52.15   Building wheel for PyYAML (pyproject.toml): started
#0 54.17   Building wheel for PyYAML (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
#0 54.17   Created wheel for PyYAML: filename=PyYAML-6.0-cp310-cp310-linux_aarch64.whl size=45335 sha256=6180755536e9685dbf4baacd3bfdc04e71f7c56e2467f12a2f994e33065dd5bb
#0 54.18   Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/1d/f3/b4/4aea0992adbed14b36ce9c3857d3707c762a4374479230685d
#0 54.19 Successfully built PyYAML
#0 54.19 Failed to build cffi
#0 55.52 Installing collected packages: resolvelib, PyYAML, pyparsing, pycparser, MarkupSafe, packaging, Jinja2, cffi, cryptography, ansible-core, ansible
#0 58.06   Running setup.py install for cffi: started
#0 59.47   Running setup.py install for cffi: finished with status 'error'
#0 59.50   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#0 59.50   
#0 59.50   × Running setup.py install for cffi did not run successfully.
#0 59.50   │ exit code: 1
#0 59.50   ╰─> [49 lines of output]
#0 59.50       
#0 59.50           No working compiler found, or bogus compiler options passed to
#0 59.50           the compiler from Python's standard "distutils" module.  See
#0 59.50           the error messages above.  Likely, the problem is not related
#0 59.50           to CFFI but generic to the setup.py of any Python package that
#0 59.50           tries to compile C code.  (Hints: on OS/X 10.8, for errors about
#0 59.50           -mno-fused-madd see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/
#0 59.50           Otherwise, see https://wiki.python.org/moin/CompLangPython or
#0 59.50           the IRC channel #python on irc.libera.chat.)
#0 59.50       
#0 59.50           Trying to continue anyway.  If you are trying to install CFFI from
#0 59.50           a build done in a different context, you can ignore this warning.
#0 59.50       
#0 59.50       /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/config/setupcfg.py:463: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
#0 59.50         warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)
#0 59.50       running install
#0 59.50       /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
#0 59.50         warnings.warn(
#0 59.50       running build
#0 59.50       running build_py
#0 59.50       creating build
#0 59.50       creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310
#0 59.50       creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 59.50       copying cffi/setuptools_ext.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 59.50       copying cffi/error.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 59.50       copying cffi/vengine_cpy.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 59.50       copying cffi/pkgconfig.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 59.50       copying cffi/commontypes.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 59.50       copying cffi/backend_ctypes.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 59.50       copying cffi/lock.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 59.50       copying cffi/vengine_gen.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 59.50       copying cffi/api.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 59.50       copying cffi/verifier.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 59.50       copying cffi/model.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 59.50       copying cffi/cparser.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 59.50       copying cffi/cffi_opcode.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 59.50       copying cffi/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 59.50       copying cffi/recompiler.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 59.50       copying cffi/ffiplatform.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 59.50       copying cffi/_cffi_include.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 59.50       copying cffi/parse_c_type.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 59.50       copying cffi/_embedding.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 59.50       copying cffi/_cffi_errors.h -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/cffi
#0 59.50       running build_ext
#0 59.50       building '_cffi_backend' extension
#0 59.50       creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310
#0 59.50       creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/c
#0 59.50       gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -DTHREAD_STACK_SIZE=0x100000 -fPIC -DFFI_BUILDING=1 -I/usr/include/ffi -I/usr/include/libffi -I/usr/local/include/python3.10 -c c/_cffi_backend.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/c/_cffi_backend.o
#0 59.50       error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory
#0 59.50       [end of output]
#0 59.50   
#0 59.50   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
#0 59.51 error: legacy-install-failure
#0 59.51 
#0 59.51 × Encountered error while trying to install package.
#0 59.51 ╰─> cffi
#0 59.51 
#0 59.51 note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
#0 59.51 hint: See above for output from the failure.
------
Dockerfile:10
--------------------
   8 |     RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
   9 |     RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
  10 | >>> RUN python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
  11 |     # RUN python3 -m pip install ansible
  12 |     RUN sed -i "s@/bin/sh@/bin/bash@g" /etc/passwd
--------------------
error: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Any Idea ?
Thank you

Comment: You wouldn't get that far if there was an issue with the buildx or qemu setup. The issue here appears to be with gcc missing during the install. You'll need to install that first.

Comment: When I build normally without buildx even without adding gcc it works fine and the build sccess

Comment: Without buildx on an arm64 host?

Comment: Sorry you're right it doesn't work on arm64 without gcc and even after installing gcc the build fails. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When the buildx inspect shows the platform list here:

```
hopeful_wilson *    docker-container                    
  hopeful_wilson0   unix:///var/run/docker.sock running linux/amd64, linux/amd64/v2, linux/amd64/v3, linux/arm64, linux/riscv64, linux/ppc64le, linux/s390x, linux/386, linux/mips64le, linux/mips64, linux/arm/v7, linux/arm/v6
```

the qemu and buildx configuration is properly done. Since the build gets past several RUN steps, that verifies it even further. The build step that did fail threw a few errors including:

```
#0 50.86           No working compiler found, or bogus compiler options passed to
#0 50.86           the compiler from Python's standard "distutils" module.  See
#0 50.86           the error messages above.  Likely, the problem is not related
#0 50.86           to CFFI but generic to the setup.py of any Python package that
#0 50.86           tries to compile C code.  (Hints: on OS/X 10.8, for errors about
#0 50.86           -mno-fused-madd see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/
#0 50.86           Otherwise, see https://wiki.python.org/moin/CompLangPython or
#0 50.86           the IRC channel #python on irc.libera.chat.)
#0 50.86       
#0 50.86           Trying to continue anyway.  If you are trying to install CFFI from
#0 50.86           a build done in a different context, you can ignore this warning.

...

#0 50.86       gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -DTHREAD_STACK_SIZE=0x100000 -fPIC -DFFI_BUILDING=1 -I/usr/include/ffi -I/usr/include/libffi -I/usr/local/include/python3.10 -c c/_cffi_backend.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/c/_cffi_backend.o
#0 50.86       error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory
#0 50.86       [end of output]
```

which indicates the build needed gcc and failed to perform the compile without it. You can attempt to change the package install line to include gcc:

```
RUN apk add openssh-client bash gcc
```

But that's no guarantee the underlying application supports arm64. If you have that other platform available, it's useful to attempt to build directly on that platform with a native `docker build` before attempting to emulate the system and run a `docker buildx build` from another architecture. From the comments, it sounds like that has failed, and you'll need to work with the application to fix that.